# ¿En qué momento te cansas de SOes y su error de moderación?

Tags: discusión, moderación, convenciones-sociales, privilegios

Hace 6 Años entre a este sitio en busca de ayuda y conocimiento; con el pasar del tiempo comencé a hacer lo contrario, apoyando a las personas que llegaban solicitando ayuda… cada día me adentre en comprender cómo funcionaba la moderación, para así tratar de aportar más al sitio.

Lamentablemente la moderación del sitio no es perfecta, ni pretendo o espero que lo sea, pero he detectado que a lo que llaman comunidad es una camarilla de 10 o 15 personas que si bien es cierto aportan su tiempo de manera gratuita han convertido el sitio en un feudo.

De tal manera que existe la expresión de: “así lo decidió la comunidad y no se puede hacer nada.”

Tal es el caso de que no importa si están dentro de las normas o en un área gris de las misma… al final lo que importa es lo que esas 10 a 15 personas determinen con sus actos en el sitio.

Entonces llega la siguiente expresión: “si se ganó el privilegio tiene el derecho de usarlo”.

Convirtiendo el sitio en un lugar relativamente toxico, con palabras en el chat como:

- “hay va a llorar nuevamente”
- “aun no desarrolla inmunidad”
- “aún le falta”
- “videos alusivos a faltas de respeto”

Y lamentablemente todos en el sitio, la camarilla y las otras personas ajenas a la situación ven este comportamiento normal.

No busco respuesta a esta publicación; solo expreso mi inconformidad con la Moderación del Sitio y las acciones de los Moderadores Diamantados, y la ausencia permanente de un CM que responde cada 30 días los reportes, no voy a seguir participando del sitio por este motivo.

Les deseo le mejor.

---

***English Version:***

## At what point do you get fed up with SOes, and its moderation bug?

6 years ago I entered this site in search of help and knowledge; Over time I began to do the opposite, supporting people who came asking for help... every day I delved into understanding how moderation worked, in order to try to contribute more to the site.

Unfortunately, the moderation of the site is not perfect, nor do I pretend or hope that it is, but I have detected that what they call a community is a clique of 10 or 15 people who, although it is true, contribute their time for free, have turned the site into a fief

In such a way that there is the expression: "that is what the community decided and nothing can be done."

Such is the case that it does not matter if they are within the rules or in a gray area of ​​the same… in the end what matters is what those 10 to 15 people determine with their actions on the site.

Then comes the following expression: “if you have earned the privilege, you have the right to use it”.

Making the site a relatively toxic place, with words in the chat like:

- "There is going to cry again"
- "does not yet develop immunity"
- "still missing"
- "Videos alluding to disrespect"

And sadly everyone on the site, the cabal and the other people outside the situation see this as normal behavior.

I'm not looking for a response to this post; I only express my disagreement with the Moderation of the Site and the actions of the Diamond Moderators, and the permanent absence of a CM who responds to the reports every 30 days, I will not continue participating in the site for this reason.

I wish you the best.

Comment: En mi caso llegué a este sitio hace 10 meses, y raras veces he entrado en el chat (quizás porque soy muy viejo y mi tiempo de chatear ya lo agoté con el IRC de antaño), por lo tanto no puedo opinar sobre lo que ocurre allí.  Sin embargo, he hablado con muchos que lo frecuentan a través de comentarios y nunca he tenido ningún **gran** problema con ellos, a pesar que no siempre estemos de acuerdo en todo.

Comment: En cuanto a la **camarilla**, diría que no existe como tal.  Seguramente son los más activos (entre los que me incluyo) y como siempre ves a los mismos quizás llegas a pensar que estan compinchados, pero, al menos yo, voy por libre, miro de aprender bien el funcionamiento del sitio, y lo que hacen y dicen los veteranos, que tienen mucha más experiencia que yo, para no meter la pata.  Es decir, me adapto a lo que hay sin querer cambiarlo todo o reescribir las normas que son comunes entre este sitio y el inglés.

Comment: ¿Que me gustaría que esto fuera de otra manera?  Pues no se que decirte, aquí mi curva de aprendizaje ha subido estratosféricamente (soy autodidacta y jamás habia conocido otros programadores antes directamente), y estoy contento con ello. ¿Que algunas normas no me gustan?  Supongo que alguna no, pero tampoco me como demasiado la cabeza por todo lo que me aporta el sitio en si en general.

Comment: ¿Que se puede hacer para cambiar el sitio? Ni idea ni me importa, bastante trabajo tengo contestando preguntas de las cuales no se la respuesta y la tengo que aprender un minuto antes de aprenderla y darla, que es lo que más me gusta y divierte: el reto de saber contestarla aprendiendola.  (Evidentemente contesto cosas que ya se, pero no me aportan tanto, la verdad). Yo con eso me doy por pagado y me vale para quedarme por aquí, sin mirar que ocurre a mi alrededor (si es que realmente existe esa **camarilla** que dices),pues no me afecta ni me meto. Lo del chat ni idea,no se que has visto alli

Comment: gracias, por tus comentarios, bye.

Comment: Este sitio es un tren sin conductor ni boletero, sin estación ni destino. Es una máquina que funciona sola.

Comment: Me ha pasado en algún caso que alguien con privilegios, segun mi criterio, los usa mal en preguntas con cierto potencial y de repente termina cerrada en medio de mi publicación, pero bueno. Camarillas no tengo porque me da mucha ansiedad entrar al chat (aunque no lo crean) o interactuar de otra forma, así que soy como un lobo solitario. Pero tomando lo que dice @masterguru tampoco me importa tanto como se maneje esto y quienes son esos compinchados; aporto si puedo, tratando de atenerme a las reglas. La respuesta de Israel es buena, analizala con la cabeza fría. Saludos pana ;)

Comment: Si es que existe esa camarilla, es por que son pocos los que quieren tomarse el tiempo y esfuerzo sin obtener nada a cambio de revisar. Cualquiera puede sumarse a las colas. Pero, por ejemplo yo, a pesar de entrar masomenos cada uno o mas meses a las colas de revision, termino de acuerdo con algunas de las revisiones. En fin, espero no te vayas por mucho tiempo, aunque no somos tan cercanos, sos un compañero y aprecio a todos los compas. Asi que se te va a extrañar.

Comment: Aun recuerdo cuando ingresé al sitio. Llegué medio alzadito (arrogante), y un excelente usuario me bajó los humos (fedorqui) con su infinita paciencia y gran dedicación. 4 correcciones a mis publicaciones, y ahora siempre me ponía de su lado el cual era "Dar la mejor calidad posible". Y después de eso hasta esperaba más las críticas que los votos positivos.

Comment: Quien fue el usuario que se fue?

Comment: @Japv yo ... en mi ex cuenta de 5k de Rep... toy en el chat por si acaso...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ah ya

Answer (score 13):

Pues la comunidad como tal lo somos todos sin la necesidad de que seamos "*amigos ni que hagamos muchas cosas juntos (por decirlo así)*", en momentos vi mucha tensión entre tu persona (usuario) y otros usuarios lo que a mi parecer podría haberse evitado en muchas ocasiones, comunidad es simplemente un grupo que tienen algo en común, en este caso el gusto y la experiencia por los lenguajes de programación y ya está, pienso que aportar a la "comunidad" es lo importante, esa es la razón por la que en los años que estoy aquí ingrese muy contadas veces al chat "solo para curiosear", tampoco estoy en SO-es para conocer gente, por el tiempo que dispongo ya ni realizo respuestas a no ser que la respuesta pueda realizarla en pocos minutos, mi forma de aportar se resumió en revisiones "pero un aporte es un aporte al final".

*¿Quieres aportar con cambios en la plataforma, respuestas, revisiones, etc.?* pues hazlo, pero no esperes que a todos le guste (Si les gusta bien y si no pues lo intentaste).

*¿Comunidad reducida entre 10 y 15 personas?* pues puede ser, esto sucede porque son los únicos que son fieles a la plataforma (por decirlo así), en mi cabeza rondan los nombres de los que aportan con continuidad, si muchos usuarios mas lo hicieran así y también comentaran pues talvez seria diferente la cosa, pero muchos (incluyéndome en la mayoría de las ocasiones) simplemente nos dedicamos a leer sin opinar en el caso de **Meta**.

Lo que te diría es tómate unas vacaciones ;) y regresa cuando te sientas descansado.

Yo lo he hecho muchas veces XD, no por inconformidad sino simplemente porque me cansa el hecho de ingresar a la página varias veces por semana.

> Y solo una observación antes de retirarme de mi silla, reflexiona un poco más sobre los comentarios que realizas en las publicaciones, créeme que en varias de las ocasiones que me topé con alguna de ellas se te siente  irónico (no se si es por la redacción simplemente) o es algo que de verdad es voluntario, esto ocasiona que otros usuarios también actúen como respondiendo a la provocación. (Puede que pase a la inversa) pues no creo que las cosas se arreglen con el viejo dicho *ojo por ojo* jeje. Que hay una especie de acoso hacia tu persona (mmm pues para mi son chiquilladas XD) **No sé cómo tomes esto ultimo que escribo y no puedo hablar acerca de lo que pasa en el chat, me limito a decirte solo lo que mis ojos ven.**

El objetivo creo yo no es ingresar o ser parte de un grupo o caerles bien a todos, al menos así funciona para mí (OJO no es que vea todo lo que pasa como normal si no simplemente veo que pueden evitarse los conflictos).

No puedo decir mucho más y espero que no tomes a mal algunas cosas, un saludo...

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola Israel, podrias decirme quien es este usuario que se fue del sitio, gracias

Comment: @Japv era *ArcanisGK507*

Comment: yo .... aqui toy ...