# cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes

Tags: discusión, moderación, chatgpt

Desde hace unos días atrás he estado siguiendo la evolución de un nuevo usuario de SOes.

Sus respuestas son variadas, en ocasiones buenas, en otras malas pero en general sus respuestas son bastante genéricas.

El promedio de respuestas es también algo inusual, un radio aproximado de 20 respuestas diarias.

No expongo el nombre del usuario (o usuarios) aquí, a menos que algún moderador diamantado me lo solicite expresamente.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Va a tomar medidas el sitio en castellano sobre el uso de chatGPT en las respuestas?**

Relacionado: [chatGPT temporary banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Personalmente, me cuesta mucho pensar en seguir participando de SOes si se permiten las respuestas de una IA.

Uno de los problemas asociados a este comportamiento es que tendremos una serie de usuarios que habrán ganado privilegios y *confianza* para tareas de moderación, lo cual puede ser realmente contraproducente.

Comment: Qué irónico sería que la respuesta a esta pregunta la emita una IA. :/

Comment: Actualmente no hay planes para permitir el uso de chatbots o sistemas de inteligencia artificial (IA) para responder preguntas en Stack Overflow en español. Stack Overflow se enfoca en promover respuestas de calidad y relevantes de parte de la comunidad de desarrolladores y profesionales de tecnología, y no permitiría el uso de sistemas de IA para responder preguntas.

Comment: Si encuentras respuestas sospechosas o que parezcan ser generadas por un chatbot en el sitio, puedes reportarlas a la moderación para que sean revisadas. La moderación de Stack Overflow en español trabaja constantemente para asegurarse de que el contenido del sitio sea útil y relevante, y tomará las medidas necesarias para mantener la calidad del sitio.

Comment: En general, Stack Overflow en español se enfoca en proporcionar una plataforma para que los desarrolladores y profesionales de tecnología compartan sus conocimientos y ayuden a otros a resolver problemas técnicos. Esperamos que siga participando y contribuyendo al sitio de manera constructiva.

Comment: Por cierto, mis anteriores 3 comentarios fueron generados por la IA, pero igualmente estoy bastante de acuerdo.

Comment: Más allá de la broma, creo que has abierto un debate muy interesante

Comment: Me parece que no tiene sentido dar respuestas generadas por IA. Si alguien quisiera una respuesta así podría ir al sitio de ChatGPT o pagar por un servicio donde específicamente se responda usando IA. También es posible que alguien quiera explotar la IA para crear muchísimas respuestas por día con buenas o malas intenciones. Simplemente no se puede competir contra una IA lo suficientemente avanzada. Pueden verlo en partidas. Ni siquiera los mejores pueden contra ellas. Por ejemplo Stockfish.

Comment: El que tenga o no tenga sentido no es lo que motiva mi pregunta. Lo que quiero saber es si se tomará alguna medida sobre quienes claramente usan *cheatGPT*. Claro siempre puede haber consenso en permitirlo. Con lo cual finalizaría mi participación en el sitio.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Sin embargo, me esta preocupando bastante que se estén creando ias para todo. Con el tiempo, todos seremos reemplazados en nuestros trabajos y muchos hobbis por ias y robots si la cosa sigue asi. La humanidad deberia aprender a que las ias solo deben ser usadas para cosas que dificilmente un ser humano puede lograr.

Comment: @gbianchi me gustaria que nosotros dieramos un paso atras y no permitamos que las ias nos reemplazen. Ya esta prohibido?

Comment: @DanteS. La verdad, no creo que las IA's "nos reemplacen". Acabo de ver las respuestas generadas por la IA en las respuestas del usuario más polémico, y esa "IA que <<nos reemplazará>>" saca cosas como 2<5 == true. Osea, tanto tienes a la IA mensa, como al usuario que nomas propaga sin sentidos. Así que no; eso de reemplazar parece que se queda lejos.

Comment: @Cuauhtli eso es ahora. Pero cuando las mejoren y les demos mal uso...

Comment: @Cuauhtli creo que te refieres a `2 < 2 => true`. Pero en todo caso, ya que está prohibido usar chatGPT para las respuestas, eso no implica que la herramienta no sea útil en otros aspectos. Dista mucho aún de ser un reemplazo del razonamiento humano, pero creo que hacia allá apunta esta tecnología.

Comment: Ei. Justo a esa me refiero @MauricioContreras ;). Pero aún así, no veo como esa cosa reemplazará no sólo a los ingenieros, sino a las personas que si se esfuercen :) Yo ando más preocupado en los propagadores de chatarra y sobrecargadores del sitio que en "ser reemplazado" por palabrería y 2 < 2 == true.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/572911/822 Respuesta: Pantallazos de una IA.

Comment: El problema creo yo no esta en la herramienta IA, sino en la vagancia y el facilismo de copiar y pegar la respuesta sin revisarla y corregir posibles errores

Comment: @PatricioMoracho que le preguntaste? ChatGPT responde a lo que le preguntas y rara vez te contradice.

Comment: @Braiam, simplemente copie el texto de esta pregunta a ver que decía.

Answer (score 16):

SOes es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. En principio no hay razón para rechazar una respuesta de un bot, eso seria "discriminación de especie" o algo así.

Si la respuesta es buena, lo agradecerá el OP y quienes consulten después.

El problema es que también vienen malas respuestas que gracias a su buena redacción y presentación, parecen buenas.

En este caso [Como modificar un archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/572145/como-modificar-un-archivo-txt-csv-completo-en-python) tenemos dos respuestas del mismo autor, que si bien son correctas en cuanto a sintaxis, presentan serios problemas de diseño, como se comenta en la misma respuesta.

Ambas respuestas son tan diferentes en estilo, que no pueden haber sido escritas por la misma persona.

¿Quién va a certificar ahora la calidad de las respuestas en SOes?

Vengo, como muchos, a responder preguntas interesantes, no a revisar/censurar el trabajo de otros.

Tampoco veo el sentido de participar en un sitio infecto de bots.

O sea, me iria a otra parte si esto no para.

***Solución***

Vienen por la gloria, le cerramos la cuenta.

Son fáciles de detectar:

- Cuenta nueva, de días.
- Cero preguntas.
- 20+ respuestas al día.

Con eso ya un administrador puede revisarlos caso a caso. Se pueden confirmar mirando:

- Excelente redacción.
- Inconsistencias de estilo.
- Errores de lógica absurdos.

Comment: Perdón? Alguna duda? Puedes escribirme por interno cuando gustes. Quieres un listado de preguntas donde tu "calidad de las respuestas" es atacar a quién pregunta en vez de intentar dar algún tipo de ayuda a su problema?

Comment: @CristianZúñiga. No estoy aquí para ser simpático. No se me conoce por ser simpático, pero doy buenas respuestas, correctas y originales. Si, ataco preguntas tontas y respuestas estúpidas. ¿Algún problema con eso?

Comment: Atacar no es dar una respuesta. Y no hay preguntas tontas para quién desconoce de un tema. Sobretodo si ves que quién te pregunta puede ser un chico/a recién comenzando. En fin, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5429/en-qu%c3%a9-momento-te-cansas-de-soes-y-su-error-de-moderaci%c3%b3n

Comment: @CristianZúñiga ¿Qué tiene que ver ese enlace?

Comment: A esto sólo le añadiría que, si las preguntas deben tener código y muestras de que lo intentaron, ¿de qué sirve una respuesta sin código? A menos que sea una pregunta canónica, no tiene ningún sentido usar chatGPT para hablar _carreta_ (como diríamos en Colombia) sin código relacionado a la pregunta.

Comment: @CristianZúñiga como el mismo dijo, candid moe no es muy simpatico. Pero NO creo que la palabra "tonto" que usó sea una expresión acertada. Yo al menos, nunca vi juzgar a Candid a una pregunta por demostrar que el que la escribió tiene bajos conocimientos (a lo sumo si respuestas erradas). Es mas, incluso las responde.

Comment: @CristianZúñiga 1) ¿A qué te refieres con "escribirme por interno"? Aquí no existe tal cosa. Por otro lado, el que está atacando a una persona en esta respuesta eres tú, por favor evita esto y centra tus comentarios en el contenido de la publicación. 2) ¿Qué tiene que ver el enlace en tu segundo comentario con esta respuesta?

Comment: Es cosa de leer todo lo que han escrito en el chat. Eso responde sus dos consultas.

Comment: Otra opción para detectarlos: -  De repente son "expertos" en varias tecnologías. - Llevan tiempo en el sitio pero desde diciembre - enero 2022 iniciaron a "contribuir" con respuestas...

Comment: Cero preguntas no tiene por qué ser así, también se le puede pedir al bot que genere una pregunta. Las de código no sé, pero las de geología que le solicité son aceptables.

Comment: @CandidMoe no habia leido esto, pero se que no eres un bot por tu dulzura, no cambies xD

Answer (score 9):

Mientras los moderadores diamantados / staff se manifiestan los interesados en el tema pueden seguir los temas en inglés

Meta SE

- [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/289691)
- [How can we enforce the ChatGPT ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384457/289691)

Stack Overflow

- [New help center article and banner on the site about GPT-Generated content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/1595451) (Nuevo)
- [Stricter trust model in the face of bot flood?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421840/1595451)
- [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421880/1595451)

Answer (score -3):

No queda claro en su descripción si el usuario al que se refiere está usando chatGPT o no. chatGPT es una herramienta de procesamiento de lenguaje natural que puede generar respuestas similares a las humanas a preguntas o indicaciones. Si un usuario está usando chatGPT para generar respuestas en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, esto se consideraría una violación de las políticas del sitio. Stack Overflow tiene políticas implementadas para evitar que los usuarios usen herramientas automatizadas para generar respuestas, y los moderadores y administradores del sitio probablemente tomarán medidas si se dan cuenta de este comportamiento.

<sub>Disclaimer: Esta respuesta proviene de chatGTP, traducida con google translate. ;)</sub>

Comment: Ah! Me ganaron el chistesito :'D

Comment: Como la mayoría de las respuestas generadas por chatGPT, parece ser una buena respuesta pero no lo es. A la fecha no hay un declaración oficial que prohiba el uso de chatGPT en Stack Overflow en español. Lo que está mal es publicar "tonterías"

Comment: @Cuauhtli Jajajaja, creo que todos pensamos lo mismo

Comment: Pues podías preguntarle a ChatGPT en español y te ahorrabas traducir, jejeje, el bicho es políglota.