# ¿Usaremos algún "banner" o similar para advertir de la prohibición de uso de chatGPT para preguntas y respuestas en el sitio?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Siguiendo la evolución de la [prohibición de uso de ChatGPT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/289691) en el sitio en inglés ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/)) (y de forma global, a toda la red), en el mismo se ha implementado, como parte de las medidas por evitar el uso de ChatGPT, un "banner" a modo de advertencia a quienes visitan el sitio, tanto para usuarios registrados como los que no lo están y un [artículo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) en el Centro de Ayuda, acerca de esta nueva política.

## Modo Escritorio:

[image: Banner modo escritorio]

## Modo móvil:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Se implementará esto en el sitio en castellano?**

Relacionado:

- [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes)
- [New help center article and banner on the site about GPT-Generated content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/1595451)

Comment: No. Y ahora si oficialmente. Vamos a generar un articulo en el centro de ayuda, y vamos a dejar una publicacion en meta como destacada por un tiempo. No nos ofrecieron mas...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido)

Comment: @gbianchi deberian cerrar esta pregunta. ya que existe algo reciente y esto se presta para confuciones.