# Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido

Tags: soporte, anuncios, chatgpt

### El uso de texto generado por [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/)<sup>1</sup> en Stack Overflow en español está temporalmente prohibido.

#### Consultar el artículo del Centro de ayuda: [Por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Esta es una política temporal destinada a ralentizar la afluencia de respuestas y otro contenido creado con ChatGPT. La política final con respecto al uso de esta y otras herramientas similares es algo que discutira el personal de Stack Overflow y la comunidad.

En general, debido a que la tasa promedio de obtener respuestas *correctas* de ChatGPT es demasiado baja, la publicación de respuestas creadas por ChatGPT es *sustancialmente dañina* para el sitio y para los usuarios que preguntan o buscan respuestas *correctas*.

El problema principal es que, si bien las respuestas que produce ChatGPT tienen una alta tasa de errores, por lo general *parecen* que *podrían* ser buenas y las respuestas son *muy* fáciles de producir. También hay muchas personas que prueban ChatGPT para crear respuestas, sin la experiencia o la voluntad de verificar que la respuesta sea correcta antes de publicarla. Debido a que tales respuestas son tan fáciles de producir, una gran cantidad de personas están publicando *muchas* respuestas. El volumen de estas respuestas y el hecho de que las respuestas a menudo requieren una lectura detallada por parte de alguien con al menos algo de experiencia en la materia para determinar que la respuesta es realmente mala ha inundado efectivamente nuestra infraestructura de curación de calidad basada en voluntarios.

Como tal, necesitamos reducir el volumen de estas publicaciones y debemos ser capaces de manejar las que se publican rápidamente, lo que significa tratar con usuarios, en lugar de publicaciones individuales. Entonces, por ahora, no se permite el uso de ChatGPT para crear publicaciones aquí en Stack Overflow en español. Si se cree que un usuario ha utilizado ChatGPT después de la publicación de esta política temporal, se impondrán sanciones para evitar que los usuarios continúen publicando dicho contenido, incluso si las publicaciones serían aceptables.

Si bien el texto anterior se enfoca en las respuestas, porque ahí es donde estamos experimentando el mayor volumen de dicho contenido, la prohibición se aplica a todo el contenido en Stack Overflow, excepto el contenido del perfil de cada usuario (por ejemplo, su texto "Acerca de mí").

---

<sup>1. ChatGPT es un bot de chat basado en inteligencia artificial de OpenAI, que se anunció el 2022-11-30. Actualmente, el uso de ChatGPT está disponible para el público de forma gratuita.</sup>

Comment: ¿Cual es el estándar para reportar a un sospechoso? Primero, la calidad de la respuesta me lleva  mirar el historial del usuario, y si veo 15 respuestas en un día, lo reporto.

Comment: @CandidMoe lo que comentas en tu respuesta https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5451/95 es la forma de detectar a estos usuarios, para ser reportados.

Comment: @Candid en especial si el tiempo en el que se formularon las respuestas no parece razonable para la extensión y esfuerzo involucrado.

Comment: Skynet esta cerca; lo unico que busca es aprender de nosotros como replicarce y mejorarce.

Comment: sinceramente una herramienta; para SO, no debe sustituir el razonamiento Humano,,, aqui es donde hay una linea gris en donde puede o no la maquina dar una respuesta correcta o incorrecta y en que proporicion; las preguntas complejas no seran resueltas correctamente y las preguntas sencillar no tendran respuesta por ser muy basicas y buscar que el usuario investigue mas antes de darle una respuesta Humana...

Comment: no estoy de acuerdo en no poder aprovechar tecnologias beneficiosas para la comunidad... Esta IA puede ser entrenada para hacer el BOT del sitio mas inteligente y no parametrico como lo viene haciendo ... dotar al Bot con capacidad de comentar cosas mas elavoradas ... seria incluso beneficioso cuando los usuarios continuamente dejan botos negativos en lugar de comentarios.

Comment: No tiene ningún sentido usar el bot para responder preguntas aquí. Si lo quieres usar, entonces dirigirse directamente al bot y consultarle tu problema. Otro asunto es el legal. Se desconoce, o es ambigua, la licencia de las respuestas provistas, además de que muy probablemente estos bots también estén violando licencias, como el gran debate de Copilot.

Comment: Tienen ejemplos de esas respuestas generadas por ChatGPT?? Supongo que si vemos tales respuestas podremos identificarlas mas rápidamente. Sera que en las Tags que frecuento no se ven esas respuestas o no las he sabido identificar...

Comment: El segundo comentario de esta publicacion te lleva a una lista.. pero igual, hay cosas que nos guardamos....

Comment: Ya vi varios ejemplos y no por este tema sino por un nuevo usuario que en efecto responde casi a todo. Lo que no me queda claro es si son humanos que crean una cuenta y le preguntan a chatGPT o si son bots. Si son humanos, cual es el chiste de responder? que obtienen?

Comment: Ya he visto muchas personas utilizando  ChatGPT antes de consultar stackoverflow ... entonces: las preguntas que realicen acá sera que el bot no las pueda resolver?

Comment: @aeportugal considerando de que tienes que crear una cuenta y que las personas tienden a preguntar donde ya han encontrado información, sería interesante dar seguimiento a cuantos usuarios que hacen preguntas en el sitio saben de esto. En mi oficina, ninguno conocía de chatgpt.

Comment: [Sin herramientas de detección](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387623/is-the-stack-exchange-community-going-to-fight-against-ai-use-with-anti-cheating), os piden algo imposible. Si un usuario es cauto y postea contenido de vez en cuando, difícilmente lo vais a cazar. Por otra parte, [generar respuestas no es el único modo de usar la IA](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1997/28185) y aquí no especificáis qué está prohibido especificamente.

Comment: ¿Política "temporal"? Entonces algún día se podrá usar supongo.

Comment: No. es temporal hasta que sepamos si se aplica una sanción mas dura. @Luis . no  tiene sentido, para eso, ve y pregunta alla...

Answer (score -1):

En mi opinión se comete un error.

La única herramienta que ha creado la propia OpenAI para detectar texto escrito por una IA da falsos positivos y negativos. ¿Cómo vais a detectar si un usuario usa, ya no ChatGPT que falla, pero GPT4 acaba de salir, y al parecer aprueba exámenes como el de acceso a la abogacía? Y AlphaCode se liberará, y vendrán mejores IAs programando en el futuro. ¿Cómo vais a detectar que un código es de la IA si el usuario da su propia explicación del código? En ajedrez se les caza con machine-learning, pero es que AlphaZero tiene un ELO de 3500 y Magnus Carlsen de 2900. Lo pregunté en Meta y me inflaron a negativos. Pero me lo pregunto en serio, ya que no tengo ni idea de cómo funcionas estas cosas. [¿Se va a iniciar una batalla de código IA/anti-IA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387623/is-the-stack-exchange-community-going-to-fight-against-ai-use-with-anti-cheating) ¿No es imposible saber si una respuesta que se podría haber obtenido en la documentación lo ha escrito una persona o una máquina? Es decir si el código de mi aplicación Android es el sugerido tanto por la IA como por la documentación de Google. A mi modo de ver es imposible detectarlo. Y más que lo será cuando Google genere su documentación con una versión mejorada de AlphaCode.

AlphaCode supera al 54% de los humanos en una competición de código. Cuando lo liberen, Android Studio o Visual Studio Code incorporarán una AI que escribe tu código y se acabarán la mayoría de las preguntas en este sitio. Stack Overflow tendrá que incorporar la IA y mostrar la solución de la IA antes de postear la pregunta.

Las preguntas se limitarán a preguntas complejas que solo pueden ser respondidas por expertos en el campo de la programación. No sé qué hay de malo en eso. Entiendo que a algunos usuarios les gusta responder preguntas. Y que a la Compañía no le hace mucha gracia perder tráfico. Pero va a haber una caída global de los sitios web (especialmente de los que ofrecen información falsa), la semana que viene Google saca Bard y Microsoft ya incorporó GPT4 en Bing. Stack Overflow no van a ser los únicos, y les espera un futuro prometedor y mucho cash ofreciendo sus propios productos IA en Teams.

Deberíais estar pensando en cómo adaptaros a los nuevos tiempos y cuál es vuestro nuevo roll como expertos en programación y simplemente votar negativas las malas respuestas y banear a usuarios que no citen la IA que utilizan (y posiblemente votar negatívamente las respuestas de la IA citadas para evitar que este sea un medio de ganar reputación muy rápidamente; es decir, el baneo debería ser de las cuentas/IA en todo caso, no del uso de la IA).
En todo caso, entiendo que la política es temporal. Yo no lo habría hecho, y estoy casi seguro que la sanción se levantará en el futuro. La IA será un asistente que usarán todos los programadores, al igual que todos los jugadores de ajedrez analizan sus partidas con un motor.

*Pido disculpas por el anterior contenido de esta opinión personal posteada con dos cervezas de más*

Comment: La politica no es anti IA.. es anti usuarios que usan la IA para contestar pregutnas sin verificar antes si la IA contesto correctamente o lo hizo de manera adecuada...  y por todos esos motivos, es que la IA no va a reemplazar a los desarrolladores.. porque, basicamente, alguien tiene que programar la IA, y la IA, no inventa nada, copia todo de otro lado.. con lo cual, alguien tiene que escribir primero el algoritmo para que la IA lo pueda generar... y las IDE, ya programan por vos, por que tienen la IA incluida y hacen muchas cosas solas.

Comment: @gbianchi salvo que le digas a la IA, fabrícame un framework y lo sepa hacer. Innovame en teoría de la programación. Lo sabrá hacer igual que igual sabe formular una teoría unificada dd la física.

Comment: Y lo sabe hacer? no creo, porque copian, no inventan....

Comment: @gbianchi lo sabrá, esto es solo un prototipo

Comment: bueno ok.. si no te gusta nuestra politica, nadie te obliga a usar el sitio...

Comment: @gbianchi cuando Google incorpore AI en Android Studio no tendré pregunta que formular. Solo creo que es más complejo que "baneamos su uso"

Comment: Para cuando la IA nos pueda reemplazar como programadores, ya habrá reemplazado a médicos, abogados, economistas, diseñadores, profesores, etc, etc. O sea, cuando llegue el día aquel, ya no habrá trabajo para nadie más. No creo que esa situación dure mucho antes que estalle una revuelta que destruya todo.

Comment: @Candid Moe Ya diagnostica mejor que médicos. Al ir a cabecera te responderá una AI. Análogamente en stack te pondrá: "does the ai answer to your question?" La cosa es que cambia el scope del sitio. Es el fin de muchas cosas

Comment: Me pregunto que haces acá. Este sitio es 100% humano, y tú has optado 100% por chatGPT. ¿Qué sentido le hayas a programar si no crees en su futuro?

Comment: @Candid Moe Me pregunto si seguiré aquí cuando Google lance una AI especializada en código. Por el momento, solo dando un poco por culo. Me pregunto si tiene sentido que qprenda más progrsmación si la IA va a hacer esa tarea

Comment: @Candid Moe Soy geólogo. Llevo desde 2015 haciendo cursos para aprendrr a divulgar mi contenido. Me pregunto si ha sido una pérdida de tiempo si voy a poder decirle a la IA "hazme una app que haga x". Ha sido un puto quebradero de cabeza aprender a publicar.

Comment: @gbianchi sí, si va a reemplazar a los desarrolladores. Los futuros desarrolladores serán expertos en pregntarle a la AI cómo hacer determinada cosa. El publicar apps para Android será cosa más de diseñadores que de programadores. Igual que en 2010 se lleno el store de aplicaciones desarrolladas por rusos, las aplicaciones se van a multiplicar en cuanto Android Studio incorpore una AI

Comment: @gbianchi ChatGPT no inventa, pero la AI sí lo va a hacer. Quizá hasta formule teoremas científicos. Es el fin, no solo para los programadores.

Comment: Ok ok.. creo que no entiendes para nada, como funciona la IA.. quedate con tu teoria de la destruccion total... los verdaderos programadores (de oficio, de arte, de corazon) sabemos que eso no va a pasar.. No te preocupes por nosotros.. deja de estudiar esto y entra en panico... Saludos!

Comment: @gbianchi :) para nada en pánico. El que le temes a la IA eres tú que como moderador has prohibido su uso

Comment: @gbianchi la verdadera pregunta pqra mí es si la AI nos va a catapultar al siglo veinticuatro. Lejos de tenerle miedo, aguardo con impaciencia como científico el si la AI nos va a llevar al futuro https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39640/will-the-ai-be-able-to-formulate-scientific-principles-or-theories-missed-by-hum

Comment: Tu confusion es tal, que como cientifico ni entiendes como funciona la plataforma.. yo no prohibi nada.. lo prohibio la plataforma.. y no por miedo a la IA. Si no porque todavia se equivoca tanto, que nos da mas trabajo que soluciones... Yo te pediria que practiques la compresion de texto antes de ser tan arrogante ;)....

Comment: @gbianchi perdona que me bebí un par de cervecillas. Comprendo que solo seguís la línea de la Compañía.

Comment: Yo no se tanto sobre ias, pero también tengo entendido que las ias deben ser "entrenadas" con un modelo, creado por humanos, en el cual encontrar un patron en el que basarse. Eso significa que es incapáz (al menos con la tecnología actual) de generar contenido nuevo.

Comment: Y si, el problema no es el uso de la ia. Si no que se esta "malusando". Sin revisar su contenido (respuestas de baja calidad por los errores en la ia) Se está ganando reputación rapidamente (sorteando los filtros de confiaza del sitio)

Comment: @Universal_learner Todas las IA que tu nombras al día de hoy son gratis y han sido difundidas en noticiarios, blogs y redes sociales, por lo tanto podemos decir que existe un conocimiento amplio de la existencia de las mismas. Razón por la cual, cuando alguien hace una pregunta en SOes yo presumo que quiere una respuesta de un humano, si quisiera la respuesta de la IA el mismo puede ir y preguntar, no necesita un 3ro que realice la pregunta.

Comment: @Dante S. [AlphaCode parece que resuelve problemas nuevos](https://techxplore.com/news/2022-02-deepmind-ai-tool-alphacode-human.html)

Comment: @Dante S. A AlphZero  el único input que le metieron fue las reglas del ajedrez, quedó campeón del mundo jugando partidas contra sí mismo. Desconozco cómo entrena AlphaCode, ya que mi ignorancia sobre como funciona una IA es absoluta. Por lo visto fue entrenado con datos de github, así que quizá sí que necesite contenido humano para entrenar. No sé.

Comment: @Yussef ¿AlphaCode gratis? Ojalá. Entonces sería posible crear una app Android en dos días. Lo liberarán y lo incorporarán a Android Studio. No se sabe cuando. Por el momento AlphaZero no es libre tampoco.

Comment: @Yussef [Yo tampoco creo que permitir cuentas-IA sea una buena idea](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1997/28185). Pero no es lo mismo una cuenta-IA que alguien que usa una IA para algunas cosas.

Answer (score -4):

Yo acudi a stackoverflow luego de encontrar que chatgpt no podia resolver mi pregunta e intentar por mis propios medios y experimentos resolverla, aun asi la mayor parte del codigo de Chat GPT me funciona, en mi pregunta creo saber cual es la linea de codigo que no funciona, y la señalo, creo que seria conveniente, hacer como una especie de alerta mencionando lo que se creo con chat gpt y lo que no y lo que como humanos podemos distinguir entre lo que esta correcto de lo que sabemos que no esta correcto.

Comment: Debemos partir de la base que la persona que pregunta puede ir ChatGPT por sus propios medios y realizar su consulta. Entonces si viene a SO debemos asumir que no buscar una respuesta generada por ChatGPT, y tal como tu indicas es posible preguntar en ambos lados. Entonces si nos acostumbramos a su uso ya no existirán 2 formas de resolver la duda, si no que en la práctica será una sola.

Comment: Por otro lado, en el sitio existen usuarios que dedican mucho tiempo a revisar la calidad de las respuestas. El suso de ChatGPT ha puesta una carga considerable de trabajo, respuestas que ya existen en otro medio, no es el fin del sitio copiar conocimiento sino que es generarlo. Tu apuntas a un uso racional de la herramienta, pero lo que ha pasado en la práctica es que se ha abusado indiscriminadamente de ella, si se hubiera hecho un uso justo este tema habría pasado desapercibido. No obstante te doy el punto, en que eventualmente nos tendremos que acostumbrar a su existencia

Comment: El código generado por esta herramienta es código COPIADO de otras web. Por lo tanto, si hubieras buscado en google, hubieras llegado a la misma conclusión. Todos a la larga, estamos copiando codigo. Sin embargo, ChatGPT no atribuye a los lugares de donde copio lo que te informa, por lo tanto, lo consideramos plagio.