# Medidas contra chatGPT

Tags: discusión, cuentas-de-usuario, chatgpt

Hemos visto el actuar de los copiones del chatGPT. Quien lo usa tiene un problema de valores básicos: llega mintiendo haciendo como que son sus respuestas y quiere ganar puntos y medallitas con trampas y sin esfuerzo.

No es nuestra labor la reforma moral de tales personas. No tienen los requisitos para estar aquí, no los queremos aquí y no es razonable esperar que aprendan algo si sólo se limitan a copiar y trampear desvergonzadamente.

Para los usuarios activos en el sitio se está volviendo tedioso esta diaria labor de revisar, evaluar y reportar copiones. Es un tiempo que estaría mejor dedicado a cosas más productivas.

Mis proposiciones para el sitio:

- Limitar la cantidad de respuestas a los usuarios novatos a una por día durante un tiempo inicial por determinar
- Limitar la cantidad de respuestas diarias por usuario. En principio propongo un límite de tres. ¿Alguien ha dado regularmente más de tres respuestas al día?
- Cancelar las cuentas de copiones chatGPT. Suspenderla por unos días no cambiara para nada al copión, ni hará que modifique su conducta. Incluso si así fuera, el copión es un ignorante con respuestas sin valor.

Comment: A mi lo que me llama la atención es que la [política de prohibición de uso de ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido?cb=1) sea "temporal" y no "definitiva". Esto da 2 posibilidades: A futuro se permitrá usar ChatGPT, o se no se permitirá. Pero, ¿si quisieran hacerla definitiva, porqué hacerla temporal antes? Dicen que será algo que se discutirá con la comunidad. Hay usuarios que harán _lobby_ para permitir ChatGPT, (__copiones o no__, sin ánimos de ofender nadie). Las posiciones sobre el tema son bastante diversas.

Comment: Yo entendi lo de "temporal" como un tiempo para estudiar el problema antes de ver una política definitiva. Creo que ya llego esa hora.

Comment: Lo del límite para de respuestas por día por usuario no me parece justo. Quizá sea mejor regular el número de respuestas de acuerdo a la antigüedad, reputación y/o puntaje de las últimas respuestas del usuario.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la medida 1 y la 3, con la medida 2 no estoy de acuerdo, los usuarios que llevan tiempo no pueden pagar las novatadas de otros, quizá pueda implementarse una medida que mientras más reputación tiene un usuario más respuestas puede dar, hasta llegar a un límite. Aunque no creo q en la comunidad inglesa estén de acuerdo, ya que allí en un mes hay usuarios que hacen 30 000 ptos

Comment: Yo no estoy de acuerdo con 1 y 2. Además yo creo que el problema no está limitado a usuarios nuevos, solo que ha sido más fácil detectarlos.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo.

Comment: En algun momento los sitios web de contenido en general van a tener una guerra campal vs las IA/Boots etc... agregar una regla mas o una normativa ... no lo va a solucionar... ademas lo que hace chatGPT es lo mismo que muchos usuarios aqui hacen... dar respuestas a media o respuestas que esquivan lo que el OP espera. y nada de eso se arregla coarteando la plataforma...

Comment: el problema de usar ChatGPT es que el usuario que lo usa / Implementa no prueba las respuesta o no las verifica antes de colocarlas en el sitio... de todas las respuestas esas son las que deben ser sancionadas ... como malas respuestas algo que ya existe en esta plataforma.

Comment: entonces como van a detectar respuestas que fueron dadas con copilot?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 la detección es simple, la mayoría de chatGTPeros son ociosos y por ello, copian todo y pegan todo, incluyendo `copy code` un par de palabras que revelan el uso de dicha herramienta. Suelen iniciar con la palabra "Para" seguida de la instrucción dada, tiene un párrafo iniciando "Por ejemplo", y las últimas palabras son del tipo atención al cliente: "si tienes otra pregunta, hazla saber para ayudarte." Otro detalle que los revela: en menos de 1 hora tienen 3-4 o más respuestas y la alerta salta cuando son etiquetas diferentes. Hay una excepción si tienes 35 años de experiencia :v

Comment: **ArcanisGK507** miembro desde hace 21 días sin una tan sola pregunta, ni respuesta. Tiene 218 puntos y 5 medallas no se de que. Como se consiguen puntos sin Preguntar/Responder??

Comment: @OCHOA hay algo raro en el sistema, Arcanis tiene tiempo en SOes, también tiene preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: ok, entonces retiro mi comentario. Solo tenia esa duda. Con respecto al tema original, yo no estoy de acuerdo con la 1 y 2. Porque? 1- Para detectar **ChatGPT Users** necesitamos que respondan y se den a conocer. 2- Hay días que ando "On Fire" y respondo mucho, otros días nada. Para mi lo mejor es, que los que tienen poder (porque no se cuantos puntos se necesitan) reporten una respuesta creada por IA, y que casi de inmediato si 3 o mas votos la clasifican como una respuesta IA se elimine la respuesta y al usuario. Mas tardaran ellos en preguntar y copiar de ChatGPT que en que SOes los banee.

Comment: Yo creo que primero deberíamos preguntarnos si estos cambios son posibles para SO-es solamente, ya que es difícil que en la versión inglesa u otras comunidades  quieran tratar el problema de la misma forma que nosotros. En todo caso pienso que deberían pronunciarse los usuarios que les afecta que se limite la cantidad de respuestas y así talvez obtener una media de las respuestas que pueden hacer en un día. Aunque por los años que estuve viendo a bastantes usuarios, tarde o temprano van bajando esa media de respuestas al día, imagino que se van quedando sin tiempo para responder.

Comment: Tuve que mirar que era eso de ChatGPT, tras mirarlo intentaré posicionarme en dicha cuestión. ChatGPT es una herramienta nueva, un una nueva librería, una nueva forma de hacer las cosas, ChatGPT se puede considerar un nuevo paradigma que ayudará a mejorar el sitio, los que buscan soluciones rápidas para simplemente hacer CopyPaste o buscar la respuesta fácil a un ejercicio escolar, ahí pueden encontrar la respuesta, para aquellos que intentamos aprender, comprender o innovar el intercambio con programadores más expertos o hábiles, no nos afectará.

Comment: Continuación...  De hecho pienso que a la larga eliminará el ruido innecesario que se genera con preguntas sin respuesta o con malas respuestas a malas preguntas. Por lo que voto por permitir (limitado) su uso y penalizar a los que solo proporcionan soluciones basadas en ChatGPT, quitándoles puntuación y privilegios.

Comment: La tasa de respuestas por día limitada suena razonable. El criterio es problemático (hay usuarios que revivien cuentas sólo para venir a copiar-pegar bobadas)

Comment: @ManuelRosendoCastroIglesias pero, si van a hacer eso, tiene que haber regulación. Minimo, se debe saber si el OP desea una respuesta de ChatGPT o si la respuesta de hecho ES de ChatGPT. Pues por lo que leí aquí, muchos de estos usuarios dan a entender que las respuestas son suyas. Tenemos que ser partidarios del "trabajo hibrido" entre la maquina y el hombre. No dejarselo todo a la maquina.

Comment: Además, como se ha dicho antes, las fuentes de estas ias podrían ser robadas. Simplemente tomadas de internet sin el permiso de sus autores y sin siquiera darles el credito.

Comment: @DanteS. Estoy de acuerdo, pero ya es inevitable, la mayoría de la gente usa la información de la web si dar acreditación a la misma, e incluso la repite como propia. ¿Porqué creemos que somos diferentes? Supongo que muchas respuestas, ya son soluciones copiadas de otros sitios, ahora existe una herramienta que lo automatiza. Aceptémoslo como una nueva realidad, y prohibir su uso no es la solución.

Comment: @ManuelRosendoCastroIglesias mis respuestas suelen tener código original. Si la solución está en otro sitio, lo aviso en comentario. Si publico, de forma directa, código de otro sitio, agrego el link. Si la respuesta existe ya, entonces es por que el autor no investigó y debería de ser cerrada.

Comment: En realidad, eso que muchos hicimos de "copiar imagenes de google y usarlo para nuestros proyectos" es ilegal. Copiar contenido de otros sitios con cierto tipo de licencia e incumplir esa licencia, es ilegal.

Comment: @DanteS. Totalmente de acuerdo, pero lo hacemos, unos más y otros menos. Yo intento evitarlo, pero no puedo decir que soy santo.

Comment: @ManuelRosendoCastroIglesias Y por eso debemos dejar que suceda? De cualquier modo. El problema principal es que gente está publicando respuestas de una ia sin siquiera revisar, y eso trae respuestas de baja calidad que saturan a los revisores (que son voluntarios de la comunidad). Que solucion propones?

Comment: @DanteS. ¿podemos pasar al chat para no ensuciar? ¿sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: @ManuelRosendoCastroIglesias no.

Comment: Perdon si se entendió mal, el no era para la segunda pregunta. No se como hacerlo xD

Comment: @DanteS. Lo entendí. acabo de publicar una respuesta, respondiendo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score -2):

Según la estructura del Sitio, las normas, la idiosincrasia de la comunidad y las políticas generales.

Se espera que todas las respuestas y preguntan sin importar el contexto, provengan del pulso (escritura) y de la analítica de un ser Humano.

Desde el año 2015 o antes, se vienen haciendo avances tecnológicos evidentes, en búsquedas de la eficiencia del pensar humano, esto ha dado cabida a la creación de pseudo Inteligencias Artificiales que apoyan el trabajo del ser Humano.

En este año 2022 los Sistemas conocidos como `Copilot` y `ChatGPT` irrumpen en el ámbito de la programación (Desarrollo) con tanta fuerza que ha logrado afectar la curva de los desarrollos en general, incluso adoptándose por gigantes como Microsoft, google, etc.

Estas herramientas fueron creadas con el fin de facilitar el encontrar respuestas existentes incluso mejorarlas de ser posible.

En todo caso aún existen un gran margen de error a pesar de ser la “maquina” la que sugiere las respuestas, estas respuestas traen los mismo ***ERRORES*** humanos… y a día de hoy las respuesta de `ChatGPT` o `Copilot` no son ***FIABLES***.

Las respuestas de estas Herramientas de programación requieren de un criterio analítico, quien al final resulta ser el mismo ser Humano/Usuario.

***Plagio:***

> Acción y efecto de plagiar (‖ copiar obras ajenas).
> Copiar en lo sustancial obras ajenas, dándolas como propias.
> Idea u obra literaria, artística o científica de un autor, que se presenta como si fuera propia.

RAE: [Link](https://dle.rae.es/plagio) y [Link](https://dle.rae.es/plagiar#CU0knYP)

***Por que las respuesta de las herramientas no deberian ser un Plagio:***

1. las respuestas dadas por ChatGPT,Copilot provienen de fuentes publicas bajo licencias que autorizan la distribucion completa o parcial.
2. El usuario esta realizando una investigacion similar al uso de Google, Wikipedia, github, gitlab o de otras publicaciones de la red SE/SO, a las que normalmente no se les da credito, en ninguna respuesta actualmente con o sin el uso de las herramientas.
3. La herramienta en este caso `Copilot` y `ChatGPT` son de uso abierto, tal cual lo es la Documentacion de los principales lenguajes de programacion o el codigo de ejmplo que muestra.
4. Las herramienta y su funcionamiento: lo que hace es a partir de una pregunta, idea, consulta; sintetizar un resumen brindado codigo de ejemplo sobre la teoria encontrada en su base de datos... tal cual lo tendria que hacer una persona, simplificando el trabajo de investigacion.

---

**Por consiguiente considerando que:**

1. La entrada de este tipo de tecnología en los ambientes de desarrollos es inevitable.
2. Dependiendo de los Responsables de las herramientas y de los usuarios, Mejorar la analítica de las respuestas.

**Le sugiero a la comunidad lo siguiente:**

1. Considerar el uso de esta herramienta como un asistente del usuario y no como una respuesta directa.
2. Que los usuarios que implementen esta herramienta, lo hagan con criterio y que estudien las respuestas dadas por las herramientas, de detectarse cualquier uso abusivo de la herramienta, el usuario estará sujeto a que su respuesta sea Eliminada por la comunidad. (no se banean cuentas)
3. Que la respuesta dada en donde el usuario implemente las herramientas se les pueda atribuir una label, propiedad, marca en donde se pueda hacer la referencia a la herramienta usada (De tal manera que conozcamos que estas respuesta provienen a su vez de algún recurso público con lo que se alimentó la base de datos de la herramienta).
4. Que las respuestas eliminadas sean contabilizadas con mayor severidad, para limitar las respuestas que un usuario pueda dar, tal cual se limitan los usuarios con preguntas malas.
5. Que mediante la edición de las respuestas, los usuarios puedan solicitar una reconsideración para que su respuesta sea tomada en cuenta y se haga visible (evitando el farmeo desproporcional o antideportivo de reputación).

**Sustento:**

Llegará un momento en que no podremos reconocer si la respuesta es dada por un usuario que usa o no usa las herramientas, ya que un Usuario con el Criterio adecuado, puede llegar a usar la herramienta y camuflajar las respuestas usando una sintaxis acorde a la que prácticamente ha establecido el sitio con el tiempo… el usuario puede simplemente dar 2 o 3 respuesta diarias sin incurrir en el abuso, lo cual pasaría completamente desapercibido si entre respuestas hay un tiempo razonable.

**Mis palabras:**

Realmente lo ideal es que el Sitio SOes, tenga la capacidad y la resiliencia para absorber, este tipo de situación y sacarle provecho, en lugar de entablar una guerra interminable.

***Esto es lo que responde ChatGTP cuando se le pregunto sobre este tema; se le paso el texto de esta publicacion y las respuesta de los usuarios:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu punto 3 falla. La herramienta no atribuye al autor original de donde tomo la respuesta, por lo tanto la respuesta en si es un plagio. Hemos eliminado respuestas que atribuian a CGP la respuesta. No es la idea copiar una respuesta de ese sistema.

Comment: buen dia, amigo @gbianchi acabo de incluir en mi respuesta tambien el sustento por que personalmente considero que no es plagio. en pocas palabras, son pocas las respuestas que dan reconocimiento a la publicacion original de donde se obtiene. decir que es plagio es como satanizar algo que se viene haciendo ... solo por la forma en que se hace ahora no es muy diferente a como se hacia en 2019. copan respuestas de otro lado o ejemplo, cambian un par de cosas y la publican como propias ... el 98% de respuestas del sitio serian plagio.

Comment: SO lo considera plagio al no tener basicamente ninguna informacion de donde salio. No lo digo yo...

Comment: Si es una conclucion bastante polemica ... teniendo en cuenta que las respuesta que se dan en SO casi ninguna se sabe de donde salen ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 No se sabe, pero la mayoría de respuestas son escritas por el propio autor. Antes de estas ias, la mayoría de las preguntas de SO, por no decir todas, no podían ser contestadas por el internet

Comment: @DanteS. a lo que me refiero es que ese usuario extraia de algun lugar en internet la informacion y la transcribia en el sitio. sigue siendo un plagio incluso de la documentacion oficial o ejemplos que se dan en los sitios oficial es de la documentacion, que de paso nisiquiera indican que se extrajo de ese lugar el ejemplo .

Answer (score -6):

Prohibir el uso de nuevas tecnologías, nunca ha sido la solución a su uso.
Tengo la suficiente edad como para haberme comunicado mediante Telegramas, medios postales (carta, postal, etc.), fui usuario de AOL uno de los primeros correos electrónicos, de los primeros chats en línea, de los primeros sistemas de videoconferencia, mi primer celular (móvil) pesaba casi un kilogramo, vi el nacimiento de Wikipedia (que estaba prohibida por las escuelas).
Las calculadoras, estaban prohibidas en las escuelas, después eran aceptables si no eran programables.
Mis primeros conocimientos de informática fueron en (Atari)BASIC, vi el nacimiento de la web.
Mi primer portátil (laptop) fue un Toshiva 1200HB.
Y siempre se me tachó de loco, pero no me importó. Los que me criticaban por usar esas tecnologías, hoy las usan a diario, y no pasa nada.
La Unión Europea, para proteger a los periódicos, prohibieron los portales de noticias, ahora los periódicos carecen de calidad y contenido, y no tenemos más fuentes de información, que sitios de chismes y cotilleos. Si no me creen, vean el portal de noticias de su navegador, y piensen si el contenido no publicitario es de calidad. Estoy convencido de más pronto que tarde esta ley cambiará.
¿Han visto muchas tiendas de música o librerías? No, consumimos su uso por medio de la red. El cine y la televisión, llevan un camino parecido. Casi todos vemos la televisión y las series por medio de portales web.
Cuando nació StackOverflow, y de eso ya hace muchos años, consultar información aquí era académicamente un pecado mortal.
Acabamos de ver el nacimiento de una nueva tecnología de la información, y muchos la rechazan porque les quita el trabajo, otros por que les causa problemas que no habían contemplado, o simplemente por que no aceptan el cambio.
Y todo pasará de largo, se quedará y perdurará, o nacerán otras tecnologías qu la vuelvan obsoleta, como le paso a los discos de vinilo, a los casetes, al los videos Beta y VHS, al CDROM, a los carreteros, a los limpiadores de chimeneas, etc.
Alguien me preguntó en los comentarios ¿Cuál es mi solución? aquí le respondo, simplemente TIEMPO, solamente TIEMPO.

Comment: Entiendo que el avance tecnologico es importante, pero el problema lo tenemos ahora. Hasta que no desarrollemos medidas de seguridad, no pidemos permitir esa tecnología. Que solución podemos aplicar ahora?

Comment: Si alguien con experiencia pude corregir y dar formato a esta respuesta, le estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Sobre las calculadoras, siempre estuve en contra de su uso. Las tuve que usar para hacer cuentas rapido y ahora estoy olvidando como hacerlas en papel y haciendome dependiente. La tecnología debe ser usada con regulación.

Comment: No hay soluciones mágicas, esta es una situación que se autocorrige sola, los que buscan información fácil se irán al Bot, los que necesitan realmente ayuda vendrán aquí y estaremos esperándoles para ayudarles. Limpiar (aunque sea mediante un Bot) el sitio de preguntas sin contestar, fusionar preguntas similares, dejando únicamente aquellas que están más actualizadas, (hay muchas con respuestas realmente obsoletas que permaneces solo porqué tienen muchos votos) y podría seguir y seguir.

Comment: Si las hay. Cuando las computadoras y el internet prosperaron, aparecieron los virus. Y con eso los antivirus y los expertos en ciberseguridad. No se resuelve solo. Alguien interviene. Ahora, las dos zonas se están mezclando de una forma poco conveniente. Necesitamos una solucion hasta que las cosas mejoren. Asi que la solucion, por ahora, es prohibirlo hasta que sepamos como accionar.

Comment: No lo creo, pero acepto vuestra postura aunque no la comparta. Una posible solución sería solo dar puntos por respuesta en función de (votos/visualizaciones)  
En cuanto a tu último comentario, esas soluciones llegaron porque la tecnología no estaba prohibida.  
Hay muchos expertos aquí, ¿Porqué no lanzar una pregunta pidiendo un Script que ayude? Puede que alguien sepa como hacerlo.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, es más bien un comentario sobre el pasado que no nos ayuda a resolver el problema presente.

Comment: @CandidMoe Estoy de acuerdo, la historia siempre se repite, aprendes de ella o no. No existen solucione mágicas, lo siento.

Comment: [En este comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462/#comment24136_5476) se resume el problema de que se utilice ChatGPT. Es corto y claro. Y por cierto, a revisar el enlace al Centro de Ayuda que está en el post destacado [Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462).

Comment: A mi, el tiempo no me parece una solución al problema presente (pero si a futuro). Las ias están trayendo al sitio problemas que no se solucionarán rapidamente. Ten en cuenta que la politica de prohibición es **temporal** hasta que hallemos una forma de accionar ante la situación presente. NO estamos prohibiendo una ia permanentemente.

Comment: Sobre tu propuesta, el sitio ya te da reputación por votos. Y no soluciona el problema. Para que el sistema borre la respuesta requiere que varios revisores (o alguien con ciertos privilegios, que son pocos) decida que debe ser borrada.