# Banner en las respuestas para avisar que no admitimos contenido generado por IA

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-en-revisión

Según la publicación en [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/141717) podemos pedir que agreguen un banner en cada respuesta generada, para tratar de evitar que se generen respuestas copiadas de una IA.

Aunque se aclara que esto no baja la cantidad de respuestas, sí puede generar que algún usuario nuevo se retracte antes de generar esta clase de contenido.

Si la comunidad está de acuerdo, podemos agregar dicho banner en nuestro sitio (esto se hace a pedido).

Dejo dos respuestas para ver la factibilidad de esto, también esta propuesta queda abierta por una semana, momento en el cual tomaremos la decisión que quiera la mayoría.

---

Post original traducido:

#### tl;dr

Recientemente realizamos un [experimento](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) para probar un banner que resalta el Política de "contenido generado por IA" en Stack Overflow. La próxima semana graduaremos el experimento que se ejecutó en Stack Overflow y agregaremos funcionalidad para permitir que el banner de política "contenido generado por IA" se habilite en Stack Overflow y todos los demás sitios de la red Stack Exchange. El grupo variante no tuvo un impacto significativo en las tasas de respuesta; sin embargo, sí vio una reducción en las publicaciones marcadas por contenido generado por IA. Consulte [la publicación en MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) para obtener más detalles sobre los resultados del experimento. .

El banner en SO se parecía a esto:

[image: Image showing the answer field, in focus, with a banner saying "Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more"]

#### Proximos pasos:

- Todos los sitios de la red Stack Exchange podrán participar (la función está desactivada de forma predeterminada en toda la red)
- Inicialmente ofreceremos dos opciones de texto de banner a las que todos los sitios de la red Stack Exchange pueden optar. Esas opciones son las siguientes:

  - `**Recordatorio**: Las respuestas generadas por herramientas de Inteligencia Artificial no están permitidas en [Nombre del sitio]. Más información`
  - `**Recordatorio**: Las respuestas generadas por herramientas de Inteligencia Artificial deben citarse en [Nombre del sitio]. Más información`
- El banner se mostrará una vez que los usuarios seleccionen el campo de respuesta.
- El [banner “nuevo colaborador”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287) ya no se mostrará en el campo de respuesta.
- Todos los usuarios verán este banner cuando publiquen una respuesta con la opción de descartar. Una vez descartados, los usuarios que hayan iniciado sesión no volverán a ver este banner.

#### "¿Cómo puedo habilitar esto en mi sitio?"

Si cree que esto es algo que su comunidad está interesada en participar, inicie una discusión en su sitio Meta para obtener consenso de la comunidad sobre el curso de acción apropiado.

Ambas opciones tienen un enlace "Más información", que apuntará a un artículo del centro de ayuda por sitio, cuyo contenido también debe ser parte de la discusión de la comunidad; este artículo debe explicar cuál es la política del sitio sobre el contenido generado por IA ([aquí está el artículo de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy), como ejemplo).

Una vez que se alcance un consenso,envíelo al equipo de gestión de la comunidad agregando la etiqueta [status-review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca), para que el equipo pueda evaluar la solicitud.

Comment: La plataforma tiene alguna forma de detectar que la respuesta se genero por una IA, de no tenerla, el banner solo será informativo, es decir no se evita que se de una respuesta generada por una IA

Comment: O sea en mi opinión da lo mismo que haya banner o no, no hay diferencia

Comment: También podríamos hacer un banner que diga que el código no va como imagen

Comment: **Prefiero que en el Centro de Ayuda diga algo como:** _en este sitio no se aceptan  respuestas generadas por IA._ con tal de que sea una politica/norma del sitio y no un banner de sugerencia.

Comment: @gbianchi el problema con los banner es que no pueden ser citados adecuadamente en un comentario de una respuesta. y el argumento de... no leiste el banner es vago ... prefiero decir... aqui lo dice el centro de ayuda ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover [Eso ya está](/help/gpt-policy), y también [hay un post al respecto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462). El banner es el punto, ya que se hace _a pedido_, tal como se indica [en el mismo post de meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881) que se cita en este post.

Comment: ok gracias, no habia visto lo de la ayuda, y lo del post me parece raro que a pesar de estar en la ayuda como una norma del sitio aun diga temporal el post al respecto...

Comment: @Japv En mi opinión si hay diferencia en que haya un banner o que no lo haya, muchos usuarios ni se molestan en ir a leer las normas del sitio, que haya un banner a la hora de responder recordando eso, puede hacer replantear al usuario si publicar la respuesta generada por IA o no, obviamente, eso no evita que la gente siga publicando respuestas generadas por IA, pero puede que haya usuarios que, al leer el banner,se retracten de publicar ese tipo de contenido.

Comment: @Marc todo depende. Es posible que la mayoría de usuarios que no leen las normas, les importe poco y nada el banner por la misma razón que por la que no leen las normas. Yo vote a favor para ver como nos va.

Comment: @Marc claro, ocurre igual que con las cajetillas de cigarro, que viene un texto que dice "fumar daña su salud", pero igual las siguen vendiendo/comprando y fumandolas

Comment: si no se molestan en leer el centro de ayuda que es una pagina dedicada al tema... que les hace pensar que leeran un texto en un box a 10 o 9 px ... jajajajajajaja

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover lo que me hace pensarlo es que, primero, es un texto corto, segundo, que aparecerá a la vista. Ambas cosas harán que haya una mayor tendencia a la lectura de dicho texto. Obvio, hay usuarios que no les importa nada y lo ignorarían, aun habiendo leido. Pero, al menos, los casos de publicaciones-ia se verán reducidas.

Answer (score 16):

Estoy de acuerdo con poner un banner

Comment: **Prefiero que en el Centro de Ayuda diga algo como:** _en este sitio no se aceptan  respuestas generadas por IA._ con tal de que sea una politica/norma del sitio y no un banner de sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy en desacuerdo con agregar un banner

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo. Si están en desacuerdo, se vota positivo a esta respuesta, no?

Comment: @DanteS. claro...

Comment: @DanteS. bueno son personas ignorantes que no saben usar el sistema de votacion para META y para me imagino que son los mismos que votan en el sitio principal a diestras y siniestras...