# Cerrar preguntas a usuarios que no marcan sus preguntas como respondidas

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas, moderación, reportes

**Propuesta:**

Consideraría la comunidad cerrar preguntas a usuarios que no marcan sus preguntas como respondidas (abuso sin seguimiento a preguntas anteriores que recibieron respuesta).

**Justificación (Motivo de la propuesta):**

Es comprensible y común, que un usuario que esporádicamente una vez en su vida visite el sitio, haga una pregunta y no le dé seguimiento a la respuesta.

Lo que para mí opinión como usuario, voluntario y miembro activo de esta comunidad, **al igual que para otros compañeros, y concideramos no es aceptable**, es que un usuario abuse del sitio y de los usuario y no complete las mecánicas del sitio, en donde un usuario tiene más de 8 preguntas a la que se le dieron muy buenas respuesta y el usuario no marca ninguna como respondida.

**Herramienta actual Existente**

Ya existe una sección en el menú de cierre para reportar abuso, ¿puede encajar este tipo de comportamiento en esta sección de reporte, y meter estas preguntas en la cola de cierre?

[image: Introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Métrica:**

Cerrar nuevas publicaciones a usuarios con 8 o mas preguntas que hayan sido respondidas y no se les ha dado seguimiento (marcada como respondida)

***Nota: esta métrica debe ser re-evaluado y consensuada con la comunidad.***

**El Objetivo (Mecánica):**

1. no se cierran las preguntas anteriores, solo las nuevas de ese usuarios.
2. el usuario puede marcar las preguntas anteriores como respondidas, y solicitar la re-apertura de la nueva
3. la pregunta cerrada en cuestión, puede recibir comentarios y ser editada, el que esté cerrada solo limitara a que el usuario reciba una nueva respuesta sin antes haber evaluado o dado seguimiento a las anteriores (ya esto es asi).

Importante que si se emite este tipo de acción en contra de alguien hay que espumearle el siguiente link:

[¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428)

Para que el usuario tenga un feedback completo y comprenda el motivo de cierre.

## Vote en la respuesta de abajo por favor.

***Conclusión:*** de momento no se hara nada al respecto, no se pudo llegar a un concenso y la moderacion no apoya esta propuesta.

**Update:**

solo para que no caigan en el error:

Hacer comentarios a usuarios de que deben seleccionar una respuesta y marcarla como que responde, sea propia o de otro... **se concidera ruido** y esto es sancionable:

> Esto fue lo indicado: [Link 1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5624/315134)

sin embargo, decirle al usuario que esa funcionalida existe si es correcto uncluso enviarlo a leerla en el meta:

> Hola, te recomiendo leer sobre esto [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428) te dara una mejor idea de como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Para clarificar, propones cerrar la pregunta o que la reportemos ???

Comment: las dos cosas ... el que pueda emitir voto de cierre que lo haga, el que no tenga ese privilegio que envie el reporte a la cola, y el que pesque a alguien y no pueda hace ni una ni la otra que se comunique con un moderador XD

Comment: al final termina cerrada la pregunta y el usuario deberia ser contactado por la comunidad o por un moderador.

Comment: A los moderadores les va a fascinar la idea xD

Comment: es una manera de forzar que la cultura del sitio sea seguir las mecanicas de publicacion, dialogo y finalización...

Comment: Muy de acuerdo, es una forma de hacer justicia a quien dedica tiempo y esfuerzo a responder preguntas, y pensar que hubo un moderador que no me apoyo cuando le pedí que le enviara un mensaje a un usuario que tiene este mal hábito como práctica

Comment: Propongo un plazo de una semana para votar

Comment: ¿Cuál sería el motivo de cierre? ¿La pregunta solo se va a reabrir si se acepta una respuesta?

Comment: @padaleiana el motivo de cierre seria el que se indica en la propuesta, ha si se reabriria si se aceptan las respuesta que se han dado...

Comment: Yo estoy totalmente en desacuerdo con esta propuesta. Si bien es muy deseable que el OP marque una respuesta como aceptada (para indicar a futuros visitantes que la respuesta fue válida para el OP), las posibles respuestas de la publicación pueden ser muy validas para otros usuarios que tengan  el mismo problema, y ver que la pregunta está cerrada puede dar la falsa sensación de que las respuestas no son válidas. Creo que seguimos dando vueltas al tema de la reputación, cuando lo importante es la base de conocimiento que se crea en el sitio.

Comment: Por cierto, en ningun caso "Irrespetuoso o abusivo" encajaría en este caso como motivo de cierre, tambien en mi opinión. Yo, como moderador diamantado, no aceptaría esa razón dado que la publicación es totalmente correcta, a pesar de que el autor de la pregunta no acepte ninguna respuesta, algo que puede estar motivado por muchas razones, desde el desconocimiento, el abandono de la pregunta por el que la hizo, o que a pesar de recibir buenas respuestas ninguna encaje exactamente con lo que necesitaba. Ninguno de esos comportamientos son irrespetuosos ni abusivos

Comment: Coincido con Pikoh, eso no demuestra ningun abuso ni falta de respeto. Tampoco se porque has planteado la publicación como una publicación de algo que se debe aceptar o no. En META siempre ha funcionado de la misma manera, si la propuesta tiene votos positivos se valora, no entiendo el hecho de poner 3 respuestas para que se voten, las cuales, pueden no coincidir con la opinión de algunos usuarios.

Comment: @Pikoh el escenario es el siguiente: Tienes un OP con 4 o más preguntas con respuestas correctas, se le ha dicho al OP que la marque alguna, el OP se resiste sin dar explicaciones. Es desde la quinta pregunta en adelante las que se cierran, para impedir que siga abusando del sistema, las anteriores no se tocan.

Comment: @Yussef no discutas con los moderadores, ellos son los que manejan todo, si uno dice que no le Interés olvídate de todo y recoje las cosas... 

Comment: siempre van a salir por la tangente... una cortina de humo o cualquier quinta pata del gato para evitar propuestasque cambien cosas en la comunidad o el sitio...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Ya, pero tampoco te pongas en esa posición. Pikoh, Marc y otros tienen todo el derecho a estar en contra de la propuesta.

Comment: Y se cerraria con que motivo?? de paso, una vez cerrada no se puede aceptar una respuesta, con lo cual, cual seria el motivo para reabrirla??  y otra cosa, si OP no edita su publicacion, los unicos que podemos reabrirla somos los moderadores. Y si quieren otra cosa mas, en ningun lugar se obliga a aceptar respuestas... se sugiere aceptarlas por todos lados... pero nadie esta obligado...

Comment: no se trata de eso @gbianchi no has comprendido lo mas minimo de la propuesta... creo que deberiamos hacer un meet como los que sugiere fredy para dialogarlo y ver si hay concenso pero con la postura y los comentarios que han dado los moderadores, incluso asumiria que no leyeron la propuesta en lo mas minimo...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Lei todo. Tu propuesta es cerrar las preguntas de los usuarios que no aceptan las respuestas. Que parte no entendi? y que parte de mi comentario te deja dudas sobre si lei todo? creo que te estoy haciendo preguntas validas sobre tu propuesta, y te estoy dando puntos validos sobre problemas que podrias encontrar en esto.

Comment: no, las preguntas son iguales a las que hizo pikoh, que respondio yussef... asique no leiste los comentarios tampoco, ni entendiste el contexto de la propuesta, voy a editarla a ver si la propuesta (el escrito) llega a mejor puerto...

Comment: @gbianchi Creo que te equivocas se puede aceptar respuestas y votar en preguntas cerradas, solo si están bloqueadas no se puede hacer

Comment: No podes aceptar respuestas en preguntas cerradas... tampoco podrias generar nuevas respuestas. Lo de votar, si, nunca dije que no se podia votar...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91827/can-an-answer-of-a-closed-question-be-accepted

Comment: Y por otro lado las preguntas también se pueden reabrir sin haberlas editado. La edición las envía de forma automática a la cola de reapertura, pero uno siempre puede votar manualmente para reabrir sin que se haya editado

Comment: habran un chat por favor ... ya mucho comentario y poco progreso ... @gbianchi

Comment: @Marc por que si es como lo esta planteando ahora la moderacion ... https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5620/banner-en-las-respuestas-para-avisar-que-no-admitimos-contenido-generado-por-ia

Comment: y solamente existen 3 opciones que no requieren cambios generales en el sitio o la red ... que son practicamente competencia de los mismo usuarios que moderan el sitio ...

Comment: La idea tampoco es obligar a un usuario a aceptar las respuestas, siempre y cuando exista un motivo para ello, un simple "ninguna respuesta me ha funcionado" es suficiente para mi

Comment: @Marc Las competencias se conceptualizan como una combinación de conocimientos, capacidades o destrezas, y actitudes... para aclarar que es competencia de los usuarios que moderan...

Comment: @Yussef [_Si suficientes usuarios concuerdan, la pregunta se abrirá y **podrá aceptar respuestas.**_](/help/closed-questions)

Comment: @Yussef mi error con lo de las cerradas y la aceptacion.. ok..

Comment: @Marc atrevete a decirle lo mismo a gbianchi en esta publicación https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5620/banner-en-las-respuestas-para-avisar-que-no-admitimos-contenido-generado-por-ia

Comment: @Japv el no lo va a hacer ... ese es su cuate ...

Comment: Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150809/discussion-on-question-by-francisco-nunez-ia-lover-cerrar-preguntas-a-usuarios-q);

Comment: @gbianchi mil gracias

Comment: @Japv ¿Podrías explicar qué debería Marc "atreverse a decir lo mismo"? Además, la publicación a la que hacés referencia es una propuesta en base a lo que se solicitó en [meta.se]. Justamente en ese post que mencionás está el enlace al post a Meta.SE.

Comment: @padaleiana a lo que se refiere Japv es que el cuestiona mi formato de propuesta... cuando otras propuesta se han presentado con el mismo formato y no fue cuestionado ... si comprendes el punto ... pareciera persecucion o buscarle la quinta pata al gato para demeritar por cual quier via/metodo o argumento la propuesta actual... cosa que no hace el sr Marc cuando es un moderador el que publica la propuesta... venga de META general o de la comunidad esta ...

Comment: "Cosa que no hace el sr Marc cuando es un moderador el que publica la propuesta": No podés afirmar porque sí (sí, se te ha dicho lo mismo varias veces; además ¿cómo podés asegurar que "porque es un moderador" no le dice lo mismo?), y se lo pregunté a Japv porque es él quien hizo el comentario. Por otra parte, _la quinta pata_ es la que buscás cada vez que no se está de acuerdo con lo que mencionás (no, no te ataco). Emitís comentarios totalmente innecesarios, y actuás a la defensiva cuando se hacen preguntas válidas. Dicho esto, no pienso continuar debatiendo una y otra vez por lo mismo.

Comment: varias veces? pediste Un explicación  y se te dio ...

Comment: @padaleiana el comentario era para Marc que fue quién cuestionó el formato de la publicación

Comment: @Japv entonces: ¿le estabas sugiriendo que también cuestione el formato de la otra propuesta? Lo pregunto explícitamente como para que no queden dudas. Dando un rápido vistazo, era difícil determinar a qué exactamente te estabas refiriendo, teniendo en cuenta que él ha hecho más de una observación en ese comentario.

Comment: @padaleiana estamos discutiendo por algo realmente intrascendente, pero me resulta gracioso que la otra publicación tiene exactamente las mismas características que esta, y sin embargo viene y crítica el formato de esta, para mí indirectamente está criticando la otra también, pero vamos es algo sin importancia, critica por aki, y por alla participa

Comment: @Japv a eso se le llama cortina de humo... o buscarle la quinta pata al gato ... algo que puede ser discutico en el chat y no aqui ... llenar de comentarios fuera de contexto las propuesta que no les interesa es a lo que se dedican ... que tristesa ...

Comment: @Japv La publicación de gbianchi es una publi que se hizo en SE META de algo que si o si se debe decidir si se pone o no, me parece bien que tenga ese formato ya que no hay mucho que debatir, siendo algo que viene de forma global, estas de acuerdo con lo que ha decidido SE o no. Esta publicación es una PROPUESTA, y se debe debatir la propuesta con todos sus pros y contras, que un moderador ponga una publicación con ese formato de algo totalmente diferente, no te da ningún derecho a cambiar la forma de funcionar en META

Comment: @Marc y quien ha cambiado la forma en que funciona META?

Comment: Claro @Marc es el clásico "haz lo que yo digo pero no lo que yo hago", bueno Marc atrevete entonces a criticar la publicación en SE Meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La aceptación de una respuesta, al igual que todas las demás acciones en el sitio y en su "hijo" (este espacio) son voluntarias.

El reportar usando la opción "Irrespetuoso o abusivo" **no creo** que sea algo que vaya **a ser respaldado por los gerentes de comunidad**. Menciono esto con base en las conversaciones que he tenido con algunos de ellos como *Moderador de Comunidad electo* de Web Applications SE. El problema de no tener el respaldo de *los gerentes de comunidad* para una práctica como esta es que los cierres que de esta se deriven podrían ser revertidos por *los gerentes* si los moderadores voluntarios no lo hacen por ellos mismos, y de continuar con esa práctica podría haber consecuencias como tener una suspención de unos pocos días a un año, o peor.

Lo anterior porque "Irrespetuoso o abusivo" tiene un sentido muy específico que no incluye el no **aceptar una respuesta**, como he mencionado previamente, porque dicha acción es voluntaria.

El tema "Irrespetuoso o abusivo" es un tema complejo. Entenderlo require de ciertas competencias. Una publicación de "respuesta" no tiene espacio suficiente, ni yo el tiempo ni las competencias para explicarlo apropiadamente para la audiencia de *Stack Overflow en español Meta*. El no entender este tema, la frustración que cause el comportamiento de algunos usuarios tal como publicar una pregunta y nunca volver, no justifica el uso de este reporte por la carencia ni el desconocimiento de otras formas de motivar la participación, y en este caso específico, para volver y aceptar una respuesta.

Cabe destacar que es loable el pensar acerca de cosas que sería beneficioso que cambiar y presentar propuestas para lograrlo. Habría que pensar en otras formas o resignarse.

En mi caso, por el momento yo estoy resignado.

Comment: cito: _El no entender este tema, la frustración que cause el comportamiento de algunos usuarios tal como **publicar una pregunta y nunca volver**_

Comment: no estamos hablando de una pregunta y no volver... estamos hablando de 8 preguntas, decir que te sirvio, decir que vaz a rebizarla para marcarla como resuelta y no hacer nada ... no es el mismo contexto ..

Comment: comprendo tu punto y entiendo, hasta donde llega el concepto de _Irrespetuoso o abusivo_

Comment: Tampoco estoy de acuerdo con la intervención de un moderador, pero: (1)Como comunidad podemos establecer nuestras propias normas, por lo que esta iniciativa no tiene motivos de dar problemas con el CM.  (2)Yo entiendo la "voluntariedad" de aceptar una respuesta en que el OP puede elegir cualquiera de sus respuestas o esperar una mejor, pero no porque no se le da la gana (creo que es ese el espíritu de la norma). Y aunque no sea así; es irrelevante para la discusión porque es justamente lo que estamos intentando cambiar, que es agregar un pelín de obligatoriedad en casos extremos.

Comment: (3) "Irrespetuoso o abusivo" no se que sentido tenga en SO, pero a mi me parece irrespetuoso no premiar a una persona que desinteresadamente le ha brindado ayuda y me parece abusivo que existan usuarios con cientos de preguntas (con respuestas) sin aceptación, abusan del sistema que les permite seguir generando preguntas y abusan de la buena voluntad de los que les responden

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover : El comentario que dice "estamos hablando de 8 preguntas", esta pregunta en Meta no menciona eso. Si eso viene de algún otro lado, ya sea del [chat] o de comentarios en la pregunta, disculpa, en este momento no estoy enterado.

Comment: Si a lo que te refieres es a la métrica propuesta, en mi opinión no tiene sentido discutirla como justificación para usar el reporte "Irrespetuoso o abusivo" por lo que he explicado. Si el argumento inicial no tiene sustento válido, no tiene sentido discutir acerca de las medidas. Aquí yo no tengo autoridad para juzgar si tiene sustento válido o no a nombre de la audiencia de este espacio, yo simplemente he compartido mi punto de vista. P.D. Si ya se sabe, a través del perfil del usuario, que no acepta respuestas, pues ya cada uno sabrá si responde las preguntas de ese usuario.

Comment: no veo sentido seguir discutiendo el tema, ya llegamos a una conclusión, que tenga buenas noches.

Comment: Agregando a esta respuesta, ya mencionado antes, es que aunque no hay respuesta aceptada, la pregunta aún puede servir de fuente de conocimiento. Eso de aceptar una respuesta es IMHO un simple juguete de reputación.

Comment: @DanteS. creo que es más que eso... por que el posicionamiento en buscadores o la implementacion SEO de la Red toma en cuenta si esta o no marcada como respondida... y los votos positivos...

Comment: Entiendo. Gracias por aclararmelo!

Answer (score 4):

No estoy de Acuerdo con la propuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de Acuerdo en enviar esta publicaciones a la cola de cierre.

Comment: Para agregar un dato importante, mandarlos a leer: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/822 para que entiendan el asunto y la importancia de aceptar respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Prefiero que un Moderador cierre la pregunta y le envie un llamado de atencion al usuario.

Si continua la practica puede ser motivo de baneo.