# ¿Por qué la comunidad de StackOverFlow es TAN tóxica?

Tags: discusión

Eso no tiene que ver con programación, lo sé.
Pero StackOverFlow sería una herramienta magnífica si no fuera porque la mayoría de preguntas reciben votos negativos SÓLO por ser preguntas de programadores principiantes incluso cuando la pregunta no ha sido hecho anteriormente.

Se supone que es un foro donde se ayuda a la gente y eso incluye a principiantes y no para lincharlos o burlarse de sua preguntas.
Qué problema hay si alguien pregunta como hacer un código Fibonacci y encuentra un error y no entiende de donde viene.

Además de que quizá no tengan tiempo para leer toooooda la documentación se StackOverFlow siendo esta poco amigable con aquellos que quieren iniciar una pregunta en el foro.
Además de cerrar la pregunta casi automáticamente y no dejar volver a formular la pregunta y la redacción ni volver a preguntar hasta días después.

Desgraciadamente la mayoría de estudiantes ya usan herramientas como *ChatGPT* o la beta de *Bing* con ChatGPT o incluso *GitHub Copilot* para encontrar errores en el código antes que preguntar en este foro.

Dicho todo esto, esto sería infinitamente mejor si hubiera moderadores para las respuestas.

Me gustaría saber que opina la gente antes de que cierren este debate. **Paz**

*Adjunto este vídeo donde se explicará mil veces mejor que yo de los problemas que personalmente encuentro en StackOverFlow:* https://youtu.be/N7v0yvdkIHg
(Lamento si alguien no sabe inglés, espero que el subtitulado del video sea medianamente decente)

Comment: Gracias! Cómo puedo meter la pregunta alli?

Comment: solo debes registrarte con la cuenta que ya usas en stackoverflow, es un canal de los tantos existentes.

Comment: Creo que no has revisado, investigado ni leído de cómo funciona SO ni de sus moderadores ni demás. Esto NO es un foro. Es una biblioteca de contenido. Pero en meta se puede discutir mejor y de hecho este post/rant/pregunta ya lo han hecho cientos de veces en español e inglés.

Comment: Es justamente por eso que lo primero que decimos es _haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio_ :) SO **no es un foro**, y tal como mencionaron, es más bien una biblioteca de contenido. Nadie se burla de las preguntas. Preguntar en SO siempre debe ser _el último recurso_, tras haber investigado y depurado el código (si lo hay, ya que a veces las preguntas son más bien técnicas). Las preguntas y respuestas deben ser útiles _para todos_, no para un usuario en particular. El autor de la pregunta no debe ser el único que obtenga provecho de las respuestas que ha de recibir.

Comment: Las preguntas son útiles para todos ya que responden dudas de los usuarios. Sí hay mucha gente que se burla de preguntas y hablan con mucha condescendencia y muchas veces la gente no tiene tiempo de hacer el recorrido de bienvenida. En mi opinión y la de muchos esto está mal planteado

Comment: Aqui no hay discriminación por nivel de conocimientos, ni burlas hacia los principiantes. La gran mayoría de nosotros no linchamos, si no que dejamos comentarios ayudando al usuario nuevo para que mejore su pregunta. Los votos negativos no son como los dislikes. Se usan para indicar que una pregunta es de baja calidad (y si, en eso estoy de acuerdo con que se le da un uso un poco excesivo. La comunidad no es toxica (o al menos, no en ese aspecto), solo mantiene la calidad del sitio.

Comment: En la sociedad hay reglas. Y muchas. Si no las tratas de entender por que "no hay tiempo o ganas" toca lidiar con las consecuencias. Por que este sitio sería diferente? Cual es la alternativa que hay al centro de ayuda?

Comment: Por cierto, aqui los votos representan a gente de acuerdo o en desacuerdo, no suele ser un "ataque" a la pregunta.

Comment: Además, si buscas mejorar el centro de ayuda, te recomiendo explicar como podríamos mejorarlo para que sea "más amigable". Ten en cuenta que tenemos normas, y todos en la comunidad pueden, cuando quieren, decidir moderar el sitio y hacerlas cumplir (aunque muy pocos tratan mal a los nuevos)

Comment: Agregaste un video y solo hace falta leer los comentarios de gente que nunca leyó qué es stackoverflow, considero que como bien dice en su respuesta *Candid Moe*, que no se le pide mucho al usuario, simplemente que su pregunta sea clara para poderle ayudar sin la necesidad de adivinar lo que en realidad quiere, a ninguno de nosotros se nos paga un centavo y cada usuario ayuda según lo que conoce y logra entender sobre las preguntas, no entiendo por qué asumen que es nuestra obligación ayudar a un usuario que no demuestra esfuerzo y solo dice háganme la tarea.

Comment: Has hecho solo una pregunta en SOes y una en SO (inglés). En ambas te respondieron con cordialidad. ¿De que te quejas realmente?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio, veo que realizaste una pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/573217/por-qu%c3%a9-no-captura-el-valor-al-usar-addeventlistener , no entiendo la razón de realizar esta publicación cuando los miembros de la comunidad tratan de ayudarte a modificar tu publicación para que obtengas mejores respuestas. Si deseas tener buenas respuestas, es demasiado importante realizar tu pregunta agregando lo que trataste o investigaste, esta es la guía para realizar preguntas en el sitio [ask].

Comment: Aun no entiendo por que la actitud ... por que noto sentimentalismo en un sitio de Q&A ...

Comment: @CandidMoe Si digo que yo no me puedo expresar tan bien y adjunto un vídeo por ello y la respuesta es esa para que si quiera respondes xd. Literalmente son esas el tipo de cosas de las que se queja la gente de StackOverFlow

Comment: @OCHOA no es por las respuestas que me han dado a mi (que en este post sí que se ven un poco) sino porque la mayoría de veces que entras a alguna pregunta ocurren los problemas que expongo y son quejas recurrentes de gente que ha usado StackOverFlow y lejos de escuchar se tiran a la defensiva como ha ocurrido en este post como en muchos otros. Además de la barrera de entrada de leerte un tocho para simplemente hacer una pregunta y las consecuencias de no hacerlo sean cosas como no dejarte publicar nada en no se cuanto tiempo y lo que expuse anteriormente

Comment: @xxy te entiendo, pero si tu supieras lo mal que se siente donar tu tiempo ayudando a otros y que la gente ni siquiera se esfuerce lo mínimo en hacer una buena pregunta. Todos aprendimos así, todos algún día llegamos a un sitio/comunidad/foro y comenzamos a entender como debes comportarte en internet. Te tocara aprender. Hace más de 5 años me registre y realicé [mi primer pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105797/agregar-opci%c3%b3n-vac%c3%ada-a-combobox), todo está en saber hacer las cosas. Antes leí como es la mejor manera de preguntar acá y hasta hoy, todo bien.

Comment: Comparto lo que dice @OCHOA, si tu haces las cosas bien, acá encuentras la respuesta a tus dudas. Todo está en como lo hagas. Saludos.

Comment: Candid moe simplemente dijo lo que siente. No es un ataque. Te está avisando que no tiene ganas de ver el video. Entonces te conviene mas hacer un resumen de esos 17 minutos. Que pasaría si simplemente no comentamos esas cosas? Muchos dejaríamos ese tipo de preguntas en el olvido. No confundas criticas constrctivas con toxcidad.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no recibimos nada a cambio de participar aquí. No estamos en nuestro derecho de pedir respeto también? Y ayudar al que querramos?

Comment: Si consideras que es estar "a la defensiva" el argumentar pacificamente algo en contra de tus palabras, esta bien. Pero para mi no es estar a la defensiva.

Comment: Creo que el problema esta es que hay usuarios que quieren ver esta página como una documentación, por ejemplo: ¿Como uso localStorage?, ¿como recupero información de local storage para mi sitio?. Copio y pego su pregunta en google y enseguida doy con muchos tutoriales que ya explican eso. Realmente para mi SOes no deberia ser un sustituto para la documentación al menos que por ningún lado se consiga la respuesta. Pero yo que se, habria que preguntarle al que desarrolló SO(abreviado de Stack Overflow) cual es su opinión y preguntarle a la comunidad si quierenqueelSOes sea otra documentación mas

Comment: ha, dato interesante si puede haber caso que el software este tan obsoleto que para desarrollar con el no exista una documentación bien explicada o sea nula la documentación como OpenGL v2. Para mi fue una frustración conseguir una documentación que yo entienda de eso.

Answer (score 17):

Tratare de explicar la situación desde el lado de participante "tóxico".

No odiamos a los novatos, pero tampoco soportamos a los flojos que nos dejan caer un enunciado para que se los resolvamos.

Tampoco nos gustan las preguntas mal formuladas, confusas, poco claras. Suele suceder que tras esforzarte en entenderla y contestarla, resulta que no es lo que el OP quería. Trabajo perdido.

No damos servicio de tutorías ni consejos sobre tecnologías, productos, servicios o mercado laboral.

¿Qué somos?

Somos un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.

Tú, que estas programando algo, de repente te topas con un problema, una llamada que falla, una operación que no da el resultado.

Entonces vienes acá a preguntar.

Dices: "Tengo este código que hace esto. Tengo esta entrada y espero esta salida. En cambio me da esta otra cosa".

Adjuntas el código, los datos, los mensajes de error, todo como texto y siempre habrá alguien dispuesto a ayudarte.

Tienes que demostrar que has trabajado en el problema, que más o menos te haz acercado a resolverlo, que te falta sólo un último empujoncito para llegar a destino.

¿Estamos pidiendo demasiado?

Comment: Si pides mucho, XD ... imaginate ese OP se ha tirado todo el dia en el laburo o estudiando otras asignaciones y ahora le pides que haga su propia tarea ... cuando el viene aqui astutamente a pedir que se la hagan ... ***Tienes toda la razon no necesitamos personas asi en el sitio...***

Answer (score 11):

Creo que esto lo hemos comentado decenas de veces en meta, pero una vez más:

Si creas una pregunta donde se expone un problema o error de una manera clara, permitiendo a cualquiera que la lea entender exactamente qué está pasando y cómo reproducir el problema, esta pregunta será siempre bienvenida.
Seguramente, si la veo, la votaré positiva por el esfuerzo.

Pero eso no significa que no la vote como duplicada si es un problema/error recurrente que se ha preguntado y respondido otras veces.

Permíteme explicarlo con algo más de detalle:

Alguien que está empezando a desarrollar es normal que se encuentre con problemas que no sepa solucionar. Del mismo modo, es complicado que sepa reconocer el patrón que ese problema representa, por lo que tendrá dificultades para buscar la respuesta (¿qué términos describen mejor ese problema?, ¿qué palabras clave he de poner en el buscador?).
Por tanto es habitual que acabe creando una pregunta nueva para un problema que ha sido respondido anteriormente. Y será habitual que los expertos en ese lenguaje o tecnología reconozcan el problema y sepan inmediatamente que el escenario ya se ha presentado varias veces, por lo que cierren la pregunta como duplicada, lo que crea un enlace directo a una pregunta previa que contiene la respuesta necesaria.

Por esto mismo, cuando una pregunta se cierra como duplicada, no se recibe automáticamente un voto negativo, incluso puede que se reciban votos positivos: cuanto mejor expuesta esté, más fácil será reconocer que es una pregunta duplicada, por lo que se marcará antes como tal y podrás obtener una respuesta.

Otra cosa es que los usuarios novatos tiendan a ignorar qué se considera una buena pregunta. Por muy expertos que seamos, no somos adivinos ni trabajamos para Stack Overflow:

- Si el OP pega imágenes para mostrar código, me dará una pereza insuperable duplicar el código cuando podría haber copiado y pegado el texto a mi IDE para analizar, probar y solucionar el problema.
- Si ni siquiera pega el código y trata de explicarlo con sus palabras, será aún peor: usamos lenguajes de programación en lugar de lenguaje natural porque este último es ambiguo.
- Si pega demasiado código (toda la aplicación), puede indicar que no se ha molestado en identificar y aislar el problema.

En cualquier caso es importante estar atento a los comentarios que suelen escribirse en la pregunta. Muchas preguntas son "salvables" si se editan y se le añaden detalles o se mejora el formato, por lo que los votos negativos pueden convertirse en positivos, aparte del hecho de obtener una respuesta.

Answer (score 8):

Respondiéndote:

> Eso no tiene que ver con programación, lo sé. Pero StackOverFlow sería
> una herramienta magnífica si no fuera porque la mayoría de preguntas
> reciben votos negativos SÓLO por ser preguntas de programadores
> principiantes incluso cuando la pregunta no ha sido hecho
> anteriormente.

***RESP:*** Estas equivocado la mayoría de votos en el sitio son a preguntas que carecen de un mínimo de aceptabilidad por problemas en su edición, en pocas palabras preguntas ilegibles o que no han demostrado interés de parte del OP.

Como lo explique anteriormente en otro post, los usuarios nuevos llegan y asumen una postura "Creen saber cómo funciona el sitio" y comienzan a cometer errores que no pasan el filtro de calidad de la comunidad, ni siquiera las normas mínimas del [help center](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

**Lectura recomendada:**

[¿Por qué votan negativo sin dar ninguna explicación al respecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/955/por-qu%C3%A9-votan-negativo-sin-dar-ninguna-explicaci%C3%B3n-al-respecto)

---

> Se supone que es un foro donde se ayuda a la gente y eso incluye a
> principiantes y no para lincharlos o burlarse de sua preguntas.

***RESP:*** Aquí también estás equivocado, esto **NO ES UN FORO**, es un sitio de Q&A, Preguntas y Respuestas. Aquí nadie lincha a nadie ni se debe burlar de otras personas... incluso te exhorto a que si encuentras pruebas de esta práctica, reportes esto a un moderador:

***Reportando comentario:***

1. El icono de la bandera:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Elige la opción que se adecue a tu escenario:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]


   Aqui otro ejemplo de como luce un reporte de un comentario fuera de lugar que no aporta nada al sitio, (espero que lo moderadores hagan algo al respecto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> Qué problema hay si alguien pregunta como hacer un código Fibonacci y
> encuentra un error y no entiende de donde viene.

***RESP:*** El principal problema con esto es que llegan y muy sutilmente dicen: *"alguien puede decirme como hacer"*... o dicen: *"tengo un problema"*...(no dejan código donde reportan el problema)

En el sitio no hacemos tareas que no hayan demostrado el mínimo de esfuerzo.

---

> Además de que quizá no tengan tiempo para leer toooooda la
> documentación se StackOverFlow siendo esta poco amigable con aquellos
> que quieren iniciar una pregunta en el foro.

***RESP:*** Si no tienes el tiempo para respetar las normas del **SITIO**, para respetar a los usuarios y sus comentarios, que te hace pensar que tu pregunta o publicación serán bien recibida?, como que es un poco egoísta exigir algo así, no crees.

---

> Además de cerrar la pregunta casi automáticamente y no dejar volver a
> formular la pregunta y la redacción ni volver a preguntar hasta días
> después.

***RESP:*** Todas las preguntas que son cerradas tiene un motivo en la parte superior, cuando tengas reputación suficiente creo que son 10 o 20 puntos podrás ir y preguntas o pedir apoyo en el [chat](https://***RESP:***), además todas las preguntas cerradas tienen la opción de ser editadas y arregladas y ser re-abiertas, todo eso depende del OP.

Si hubieras leído las normas del sitio, te hubieras percatado que las preguntas duplicadas o repetidas están prohibidas, incluso si existe una respuesta previa de otros usuarios, la tuya será cerrada como duplicada.

Si haces Mala preguntas y no resuelves los problemas, el **SISTEMA** (no los usuarios) te limitará por haber hecho malas preguntas, y cada vez que hagas nuevas malas preguntas, te va limitando cada vez más hasta que no puedas preguntar, la misma mecánica aplica para respuestas.

---

> Desgraciadamente la mayoría de estudiantes ya usan herramientas como
> ChatGPT o la beta de Bing con ChatGPT o incluso GitHub Copilot para
> encontrar errores en el código antes que preguntar en este foro.

***RESP:*** Esto no nos afecta, incluso hemos hecho pruebas y de mi parte recomendaría el uso de esas herramientas antes de venir a preguntar, cuando el error pudo haber sido tipográfico, el sitio no es un servicio de depuración de código, cuando el usuario hace una pregunta, esperamos que al menos haya identificado el error que no puede resolver.

---

> Dicho todo esto, esto sería infinitamente mejor si hubiera moderadores
> para las respuestas.

***RESP:*** Lamento comentarte que la moderación del sitio se lleva a cabo por los mismos usuarios, cada vez que vas ganando reputación vas ganando privilegios y esos privilegios te dan opciones para moderar el sitio, eso no quiere decir que puedes hacer lo que te da la gana, los usuarios que moderan el sitio seguimos la dirección de la comunidad en general, respetamos las opiniones de los demás y respetamos las normas del sitio.

---

En conclucion si consideras que el sitio no llena tus espectativas para aprender y encontrar las respuestas a tus dudas sobre programacion puedes pedirle a Alex Ziskind en su sitio https://nativescript.training/ que te cotice el entrenamiento que buscas.

Comment: No sería raro que el tipo del video tratase de hacer quedar mal al sitio para aumentar la cantidad de gente que acepta sus cursos.

Comment: @DanteS. es correcto ... eso se llama etica, jamas he visto al personal de Platzi hacer tal cosa ...

Comment: No entiendo tu postura, estas negando que hay un problema de "toxicidad" (por llamarlo de alguna manera), en el sitio?

Comment: Tengo más pruebas para negarlo, que para confirmarlo... en tal caso existiece esa toxicidad existen las herramientas de reporte para manejarlo... si los usuarios no las usan como se supone que se arreglara entonces la supuesta toxicidad ...

Comment: Pero es que acá https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5429/en-qu%c3%a9-momento-te-cansas-de-soes-y-su-error-de-moderaci%c3%b3n básicamente estas diciendo lo mismo que el OP, que existe un problema en la moderación y literalmente ocupas la misma palabra "Toxico"

Comment: @Yussef si y aqui esta la respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5430/315134 por que crees que con mis 390 puntos solo me dedico a la moderacion minima necesaria ... para que no crean que usare mis puntos y privilegios para hacer o deshacer ... elimine una cuenta con 5k de reputacion para cumplir con este objetivo y hacerle ver a la gente que no necesita miles de reputacion para hacer un cambio ... y aportar al sitio. y cada vez que vea y pueda reportar algo que vaya en contra del codigo de conducta lo hare... sea nuevo o viejo el usuario...

Comment: No me gusta la politica de stack exchange de "los comentarios son solo para cosas importantes, olvidemos que somos seres humanos", asi que espero no hagan nada al respecto. De cualquier modo, eras conflictivo por que hacías lo que podías, te entiendo.

Comment: Entiendo estimado, por favor no tomes mis palabras como ataque. Solo quiero hacer ver que si un usuario reconocido por la comunidad activa puede llegar a sentirse atacado, imagina como puede llegar a sentirse un usuario nuevo. Hay un sin fin de publicaciones aquí en Meta del tipo "Porque la gente tiene el dedo tan fácil" que apuntan a lo mismo. Pero una y otra vez se dice que el problema no existe

Comment: entonces apoyen en la moderacion y reporten todo lo que creen que viola el codigo de conducta.

Answer (score 7):

Primero que nada, quiero aclarar que los votos negativos NO son ataques a la persona. Si no a la pregunta. En el caso de meta suelen representar si la gente está de acuerdo o no con lo que dices.

---

> la mayoría de preguntas reciben votos negativos SÓLO por ser preguntas
> de programadores principiantes incluso cuando la pregunta no ha sido
> hecho anteriormente.

Los votos negativos pueden tener varios motivos. Y ser de un programador principiante no es uno de ellos. Tal vez lo que viste fue que la mayoría de programadores principiantes en el sitio, hacen preguntas de baja calidad y/o que no cumplen las normas del sitio.

> Se supone que es un foro donde se ayuda a la gente y eso incluye a
> principiantes y no para lincharlos o burlarse de sua preguntas

Para empezar, esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Y en mis 3 años mirando comentarios en preguntas de Python, son contados con los dedos en los que se lincha al usuario. Y ninguno donde se burlen de ellos.

Antes de acusar, te recomiendo mostrarnos al menos un caso donde eso sucedio. En una discusión o propuesta, probar tus argumentos es importante.

> Además de que quizá no tengan tiempo para leer toooooda la
> documentación se StackOverFlow siendo esta poco amigable con aquellos
> que quieren iniciar una pregunta en el foro.

Puede ser cierto. Si consideras que se puede mejorar de alguna forma, estaría bueno que pruebes alguna propuesta y ver si la comunidad la acepta. Hacemos lo mejor posible para tener a los usuarios nuevos informados.

También aclaro que los comentarios que dicen "lee esto, te recomiendo hacer x" son en realidad formas de ayudar al OP a "salvar" su pregunta dandole información. Quizá eso es lo que percibes como burla?

Ten en cuenta que en este sitio, como en toda sociedad, hay reglas. Si no te dedicas a conocerlas, tendrás que lidiar con las consecuencias.

> Qué problema hay si alguien pregunta como hacer un código Fibonacci y
> encuentra un error y no entiende de donde viene.

Ninguno, siempre y cuando la pregunta siga las normas del sitio.

> Además de cerrar la pregunta casi automáticamente y no dejar volver a
> formular la pregunta y la redacción ni volver a preguntar hasta días
> después.

Si no cerramos rapidamente una pregunta, esta recibirá una respuesta. Y eso perjudicaría al sitio. Que raro que no te lo permita, la edición es un derecho, a diferencia de preguntar y responder, y deberías de poder editar la pregunta. NO hagas una nueva pregunta mejorando la anterior, editala, así mantenemos limpio el sitio. Parte del proposito de editar es eso.

---

Sobre el video, no puedo verlo por que está en ingles. Bueno, no hay problema. Pero parece hablar de Stack Overflow (el sitio en inglés). Esto es una comunidad que, si bien tiene sus bases en el sitio en inglés, es otra comunidad, y podría tener una mentalidad distinta.

Comment: Disiento totalmente, a un usuario nuevo los negativos le condicionan el accionar dentro de SOes, no digo que haya intención, pero dadas las consecuencias para el usuario, se "siente" como ataque.

Comment: @MarcePuente yo hablaba de lo que yo creo que es la intención promedio del voto negativo. Te entiendo, yo también lo senti como ataque en su momento. Pero no lo es. Y si, influye, es un mecanismo de seguridad. Pero para mi no está bien diseñado. Y por eso no voto negativo casi nunca. Se supone que el voto negativo debería ser "el ultimo recurso", pero no lo es, y en eso no estoy de acuerdo con la comunidad.

Comment: @DanteS. Opino lo mismo sobre los votos negativos, casi nunca los doy.

Answer (score 4):

No es que sea tóxica, el problema de varios programadores que inician es su tendencia a la falta de lectura y a la comprensión de ella. Ahora, decirles que lean y acomoden sus preguntas es un problema enorme cuando se lo toman personal.

Claramente el video ese al que te refieres de la versión anglosajona, genera y motiva más toxicidad por el simple hecho de pasar de largo el "cómo preguntar", adoptar una postura totalmente ajena a los lineamientos (recalco nuevamente: por falta de lectura) y hasta de cierto punto manipula a la audiencia para identificarse con el modo víctima: "pobre de mi, le dieron palos a mi pregunta, nadie me quiere ayudar aquí, todos saben menos yo, qué malos y perversos son los usuarios de aquí", modo que probablemente se hayan identificado en algún momento de sus carreras y/o vidas. Justamente por esa identificación "sutil", la gente trae más gasolina y prende más fuego al asunto.

Llevo poco más de 7 años en SOes y muchas preguntas preguntas de usuarios nuevos (generalmente) carecen de forma, es decir, una pregunta bien estructurada automáticamente se convierte en una pregunta con media respuesta. Personalmente, les dejo enlaces para que lean donde están los lineamientos del sitio y [unas recomendaciones desde mi punto de vista](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822) para generar una pregunta con mayores chances de obtener respuesta, a veces de tutoriales del tema que están queriendo resolver en su caso.

Hay usuarios tan vagos que hasta han dejado fotos de sus exámenes pidiendo ayuda inmediata. Reprobar una materia por desconocimiento no tiene nada de ilógico, al contrario, es totalmente lógico reprobar una materia por falta de conocimiento, al menos por carecer de lo mínimo necesario en notas. A estos usuarios, de todo corazón, les sugiero que repitan la materia, en especial si desean vivir del código. Este párrafo en sí, tranquilamente puede ser catalogado como "tóxico" por "incentivar a la repetición de una materia", ¿terrible, verdad? Ahora vamos colocando el resto de elementos en la misma ecuación: "incentivar a la repetición de una materia por carecer de los conocimientos mínimos necesarios para aprobar una materia", ¿todavía puede catalogar como "tóxico"? El punto al que voy es que se debe ver el panorama para analizar bien.

> Dicho todo esto, esto sería infinitamente mejor si hubiera moderadores para las respuestas.

Aquí tenemos un gran punto; la moderación del sitio depende de todos los usuarios que se tomen el tiempo en leer las preguntas e interactuar con las mismas. Los moderadores en el sitio te dan su tiempo ad-honorem, interpretado en español: gratis y de corazón. Todos los días tienen moderadores diferentes que aportan al sitio a distintas horas del día, en la cola de revisión existe un máximo de preguntas que pueden ser atendidas por usuario, la enorme masa de preguntas del sitio requiere de muchas horas de dedicación de personas como tú, como yo que desean aportar por el puro gusto de hacerlo, nadie nos paga, estamos de voluntarios y sí, llega un momento donde te agota ver comportamientos infantiles malcriados del tipo:

"Si sabes ayuda, sino, cierra la p**a boca". Esto sí es tóxico y viene desde la frustración del que preguntó mal, con código que es imposible reproducir y encima te tratan con respeto nulo. ¿Leyó las reglas? ¿Leyó cómo preguntar? Lo dudo mucho.

Preguntar cosas básicas está bien, nada de malo tiene; lo tóxico sería burlarse de esos usuarios y en todo el tiempo que llevo en SOes, rarísima vez he visto a algún usuario burlarse directamente en un comentario de una pregunta y/o respuesta.

Para finalizar, comparto lo que dice [@CandidMoe](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe) en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5516/822)

> Entonces vienes acá a preguntar.
>
> Dices: "Tengo este código que hace esto. Tengo esta entrada y espero esta salida. En cambio me da esta otra cosa".
>
> Adjuntas el código, los datos, los mensajes de error, todo como texto y siempre habrá alguien dispuesto a ayudarte.
>
> Tienes que demostrar que haz trabajado en el problema, que más o menos te haz acercado a resolverlo, que te falta sólo un último empujoncito para llegar a destino.
>
> ¿Estamos pidiendo demasiado?

Answer (score 1):

Decir que la comunidad es toxica es pasarse 3 pueblos (como dicen los hnos españoles).

Pero si, es verdad que hay un problema lo he visto y lo he vivido así que no está en tu imaginación.

Algunos usuarios niegan que exista una curva de aprendizaje en el sitio, "tu primera pregunta debe ser perfecta!!!", Si no lo es te caen 2 negativos, pregunta cerrada, y 5 comentarios que te dice que leas `tour` y yo aun no encuentro donde se demuestra el tan solicitado esfuerzo en el súper ejemplo de `Cómo evitar que los unicornios se coman las margaritas`

*(Y ahora que me fijo el súper ejemplo de los unicornios tiene 2 respuestas con votos positivos, anda a saber tu cuantos negativos me darían por responder una pregunta de ese calibre)*

Algunos de nosotros hemos discutimos sobre cómo ayudar al nuevo usuario, para que sus preguntas sean mejor recibidas, y así evitar todo lo que viene después,  Algunos fueron lo suficientemente proactivos como para generar una propuesta:

[Mejoras al Help Center (Detalles y Contenido)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5501/mejoras-al-help-center-detalles-y-contenido)

Y tiene toda lógica: Mejoremos y clarifiquemos **nuestras** reglas, para no confundir a los nuevos usuarios y a los viejos también, así tenemos un piso moral para exigir el cumplimiento de ellas desde el primer minuto.

Y ahí está en 10 días 78 visitas, 5 votos a favor y uno en contra.

En cambio, tú haces una crítica al sitio, y tienes varias respuestas, muchos comentarios, muchas visitas y todo eso en cuestión de horas. Y la mayoría negando la triste realidad, es imposible que se mejore con este tipo de actitud, porque no se reconoce el problema.

Mencionaste a los "principiantes", y bueno este tema en SO es debatido de hace largo tiempo. Uno de los fundadores del sitio convencido que las preguntas novatas si eran bien recibidas (ya que era un objetivo primario cuando lo fundaron), decidió generar una novel pregunta bajo un seudónimo, obviamente se la cerraron al instante.

Tu pregunta apunta al **¿Por qué?**

Mi opinión personal es que existen demasiados usuarios preocupados por la moderación, más que en responder o preguntar. Esto hace que preguntas que están en una gran área gris se cierren rápidamente, pudiendo haber sido mejoradas. Yo por eso tomé la determinación de no ejercer más mi privilegio tanto para el voto negativo como para el cierre de preguntas, así equilibro un poco la balanza.

---

Ahora hay cosas que no estoy de acuerdo contigo: es de un mínimo de respeto al ingresar en un comunidad leer sus reglas. Aun siendo malas, hay que leerlas.

Es también tener un mínimo de respeto y de sentido común, el tratar de generar la mejor pregunta posible "ponerle ganas al asunto". Es que es el que pregunta el que debe esforzarme más, no el que responde.

Y por supuesto estar atento a los comentarios, tanto para generar feedback o mejorar la pregunta.

Porque, por ejemplo, poner imágenes de código es hasta más trabajo que copiar y pegar el código como texto, así que tiendo a pensar que no es de vago. Pero si te dicen que coloques las imágenes como texto y pasan horas que no lo haces, es una despreocupación que en mi caso no tolero.

Comment: **Decir que la comunidad es toxica es pasarse 3 pueblos**, cualquier generalización, cae bajo este lema, eso no quita que haya gente tóxica, y esa gente es la que genera este tipo de comentarios, no digo que sea la mayoría, pero lamentablemente, si alguien te dice "Hola xx, bienvenido, edita tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida", y seguido recibes un "Aca no hacemos la tarea de nadie!", lo que te queda, es la mala respuesta... dices diez verdades y una mentira = eres un mentiroso, somos humanos, así funcionamos.

Comment: @MarcePuente que tu mundo este llena de personas con malos habitos no quiere decir que debamos aceptarlos ... aqui nadie es la excepcion a la regla.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, estás mezclando temas, una cosa es el supuesto mal accionar de un OP, y otra es la forma en la que nos dirigimos a el, para más inri (y explicando el "supuesto"), me he encontrado con escenarios donde el OP dice necesito hacer esto, y escribe el enunciado que le dio el profe, y que después de sugerirle, agrega todo el código que había hecho intentando solucionarlo, simplemente, no lo agregó cuando formuló la pregunta , porque no sabía que lo tenía que hacer... el supuesto "vago", no lo era.

Comment: @MarcePuente de que manera te explico que ese supuesto vago que no lo es en realidad si lo es por que le dio pereza leer el tour y verificar que su pregunta cumpliera con lo minimo del sitio para ser bien recibida ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, no y cien veces no, el usuario **nuevo** ni siquiera sabe de la existencia de el tour, te pido un enorme favor, deslogueate, y entra [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), verás que no hay ninguna referencia a"tour", a "centro de ayuda", a "como preguntar", ni a nada, si quieres tener una idea más cabal, te cuento que el OP, se encuentra con una pantalla totalmente desconocida, para realizar su pregunta, con un "montón de pequeñas indicaciones, por lo que se enfoca en ella, lo que tiene como consecuencia (me ha pasado a mi), que no preste atención a la "otra.

Comment: te dejare esta imagen de que es lo que realmente sale cuando entras [enlace](https://i.imgur.com/wBFgPW1.png) ... y si el problema puede ser que el sitio no es lo suficientemente descriptivo el objetivo es mejorar el sitio en la misma direccion que ha sido concevida... no argumentar que por que algo no se ve a simple vista ... todo pueden pasarce las normas por donde no les llega el sol.

Comment: es lo mismo que decir como escusa que vas a comensar mañana a matar personas por que la ley no esta escrita en un lugar visible ... o que mañana comensaras a sacar la plata del diesmo de la iglesia por que en la biblia no dice que no lo puedas hacer  ... osea hay cosas que se cae por su propio peso ... y en este caso si hay un lugar en donde estan descritas ... y venismos indicando que leas ...

Comment: @marcePuente si alguien viene y simplemente te dice el enunciado de un ejercicio, sin explicarte que está pasando, a pesar de lo que dice el sitio que hagas para preguntar, no hace caso a comentarios editando la pregunta (esto es el caso habitual en Python cuando se publican enunciados), crees que esa persona tiene algo de respeto por los que lo hubieran ayudado y los que se esforzaron por hacer sus trabajos? Que es alguien a quien vale la pena ayudar? Esas preguntas son una falta de respeto. Por que tratarías con respeto a alguien que no lo da?

Comment: @DanteS., yo estoy hablando de que el usuario nuevo, no está enterado de como funcionamos, y que cuando le sugerimos hacer cambios, los hace, con el que no los hace... lo podemos fusilar, no tengo ningún tipo de empatía con esos, pero no pongamos a todos en la misma bolsa.

Comment: @MarcePuente entiendo. Pero primero, como diferenciamos al que lo hace o no lo hace? En el caso de los enunciados, casi no vi que hicieran un cambio a sus preguntas. Tendríamos que darle dos dias, y eso haría que algunos usuarios respondan cuando no está bueno. Segundo, en eso te doy la razón. El unico cambio que haría es que esa ventana recomiende hacer el tour y el centro de ayuda.

Comment: @DanteS., totalmente de acuerdo, creo que habría que reimplementar el "en espera", pero distinto, que sea transparente para el OP, y que no deje responder.

Comment: no tiene sentido utilizar el "en espera" ... es doble trabajo: los usuarios nuevo debido a sus habitos solo hay 2 tipos de usuarios: 1) el que viene y deja una tarea y no le interesa, 2) el que viene coloca su pregunta y si le interesa...

Comment: por lo tanto una pregunta que no cumpla con las normas del sitio debe ser cerrada y comentada... si el usuario le interesa que su pregunta sea respondida... le dara seguimiento y arreglara su pregunta... si al usuario no le interesa simplemente se queda cerrada ... de tal manera no hace hace doble trabajo...

Comment: esto aplica para todos independientemente que sea nuevo o viejo ...

Comment: *Mi opinión personal es que existen demasiados usuarios preocupados por la moderación, más que en responder o preguntar.* Eso mismo.